# Shortest Game of Life

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, cellular-automata, game-of-life

[Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conways_Game_of_Life) is the classic example of cellular automation. The cells form a square grid and each has two states: alive or dead. On each turn, each cell simultaneously updates according to its state and those of its eight neighbours:

- A live cell remains alive if it has exactly two or three live neighbours
- A dead cell becomes alive if it has exactly three live neighbours

Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to code the shortest Game of Life implementation in your favourite language.

The rules:

- The grid must be at least 20x20
- The grid must wrap around (so the grid is like the surface of a Torus)
- Your implementation must allow the user to input their own starting patterns
- GoL is a bit pointless if you can't see what is happening, so there must be visual output of the automaton running, with each turn's result being shown for long enough to be seen!

Comment: Previously on Stack Overflow: [Code Golf: Conway's Game of Life](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3499538/2509), and be sure to look at the APL implementation link in the comments.

Comment: Ah, I did not see that. But this is slightly different no (save me deleting the work putting the challenge together?

Comment: It's not a problem. Many puzzles already run on Stack Overflow have been done here too, but people will tell you that I am obsessive about linking to similar challenges.

Comment: @Griffin: You can remove all those `;` before `}`s. Also `var`s can be eliminated at times (if it doesn't break your code). And for one-line `for`s, `if`s etc, you can eliminate the `{ }` completely: `for(...) for(...) dosomething()`.

Comment: @pimvdb, cheers, I haven't fully golfed it yet, haven't had the time. just wanted to show that I had a go too, rather than idly setting a challenge. Will golf it to the max soon.

Comment: @pimvdb, how's that? :D

Comment: @Griffin: Wow, more than 50%!

Comment: @pimvdb, squeezed a bit more out, but I think that may be the limit. I take my hat off to you if you find any more.

Comment: You can save a couple more on your inner for loops since the third argument is optional. So for(j=0;j<r;++j) becomes for(j=0;j<r;) and you move the increment operator into the statement: document.getElementById(z+"_"+j).innerHTML=b[z][j++]?"#":"."

Comment: Also, since K(z,j) always returns an integer, you can shorten your comparison n<=3&&n>=2:n==3 to n<4&&n>1:n==3. You also use document 3 times, so you can save a bit by making a variable to refer to document instead.

Comment: @migimaru, well spotted, thanks

Comment: What's the generally accepted rule for generations? Does it have to go until it reaches a stable state, or can it go forever, or for an arbitrary number of generations?

Comment: Excellent question! It's a shame I got to read this so late. Well, alas, too late, but anyway, I submitted *Mathematica* 333 character version with interactive features. I had to submit an entry for the only language with built in `CellularAutomaton` function ;-) http://wolfram.com/xid/0d6e8l44ia-oec

Comment: I can use a conway's game of life engine to win this challenge, it technically only takes the input number of cells to run. :)  (I'm just kidding though)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### HTML5 Canvas with JavaScript, <strike>940</strike> <strike>639</strike> <strike>586</strike> 519 characters

```
<html><body onload="k=40;g=10;b=[];setInterval(function(){c=[];for(y=k*k;y--;){n=0;for(f=9;f--;)n+=b[(~~(y/k)+k+f%3-1)%k*k+(y+k+~~(f/3)-1)%k];c[y]=n==3||n-b[y]==3;r.fillStyle=b[y]?'red':'tan';r.fillRect(y%k*g,~~(y/k)*g,g-1,g-1)}if(v.nextSibling.checked)b=c},1);v=document.body.firstChild;v.width=v.height=g*k;v.addEventListener('click',function(e){b[~~((e.pageY-v.offsetTop)/g)*k+~~((e.pageX-v.offsetLeft)/g)]^=1},0);r=v.getContext('2d');for(y=k*k;y--;)b[y]=0"><canvas></canvas><input type="checkbox"/>Run</body></html>
```

I always wanted to do something with canvas, so here is my attempt (original version [online](http://jsfiddle.net/RrtfS/)). You can toggle cells by clicking (also possible in running mode).

You can now also try the new version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/FPUzk/).

Unfortunately there is an issue I couldn't work around yet. The online version is 11 characters longer because jsFiddle puts a text node just before the canvas (why?) and thus the canvas is no longer the first child.

*Edit 1:* Lots of optimisations and restructurings.

*Edit 2:* Several smaller changes.

*Edit 3:* Inlined the complete script block plus minor changes.

Comment: Nice, but change the interval delay to `1` makes it as fast as mine rather than that slow stepping. Also if you want to implement drawing (rather than clicking on each square) you can round the mouse position to the nearest blocksize and fill the rectangle at that point. More characters but more points.

Comment: You can replace `new Array('#FFF','#800')` with `['#FFF','#800']`.

Comment: Though saying that about drawing, my super-golfed doesn't allow drawing and is ugly as sin. Haha. You can set your two colours in the `s` array to `tan` and `red` since they are the two colours with the shortest representations - saves you two chars. Also, if possible, put the literal version of `j` into the interval. I'm sure there's lots more to squeeze out too.

Comment: @Griffin and Lowjacker: thank you very much. I am also pretty sure that you can golf this much more (and have already some ideas). Unfortunately I didn't find the time to do so. A better golfed version will follow tomorrow - I hope...

Comment: @Howard Just tried your new version in jsFiddle and it seems to have a mismatched brace somewhere, so it won't run.

Comment: @Gareth It is not a mismatched brace but jsFiddle seems to have the canvas not as the first child element (???). Therefore my new version with `document.body.firstChild` does not work but you have to get the canvas by id again: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqPv6/).

Comment: Damn, Howard, you've blown everyone out of the water. You can save 2 more chars: you don't actually have to supply a interval delay it seems, if you leave out the `,1` it defaults to 0ms.

Comment: @Griffin I didn't get it running without the `,1`. Seems that it is not optional. But I found other places to save few chars.

Comment: @Howard, I don't have the `,1` in mine, maybe it's browser differences.

Comment: Technically, you could omit the `<html>` tag.

Comment: The attached stack snippet that wizzwizz4 added doesn't actually seem to work, so I'll roll it back for now.

Comment: You can remove the html and body tags. It will function the same

Comment: @Griffin Why is this accepted when there is [a much shorter answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12733/43319)?

Answer (score 37):

### Python, 219 chars

I went for maximum golfage, with just enough interface to satisfy the question.

```
import time
P=input()
N=range(20)
while 1:
 for i in N:print''.join(' *'[i*20+j in P]for j in N)
 time.sleep(.1);Q=[(p+d)%400 for d in(-21,-20,-19,-1,1,19,20,21)for p in P];P=set(p for p in Q if 2-(p in P)<Q.count(p)<4)
```

You run it like this:

```
echo "[8,29,47,48,49]" | ./life.py
```

The numbers in the list represent the coordinates of the starting cells.  The first row is 0-19, the second row is 20-39, etc.

Run it in a terminal with 21 rows and it looks pretty snazzy.

Comment: This totally should have won. I guess 'ease of input' was weighted fairly high.

Comment: @primo I'd even go so far as to suggest mma should have a separate competition.

Comment: So is this Life of Py then?

Comment: You can always save one more char... `2-(p in P)` == `2-({p}<P)`.
But then you would have to change your input to `{8,29,47,48,49}` :)

Answer (score 27):

## TI-BASIC, 96 bytes (87 for non-competing entry)

For your TI-84 series graphing calculator (!). This was quite a challenge, because there is no easy way to write a buffered graphics routine (definitely nothing built in), and the graph screen has only four relevant graphics commands: `Pxl-On()`, `Pxl-Off()`, `Pxl-Change()`, and `pxl-Test()`.

Uses every accessible pixel on the screen, and wraps correctly. Each cell is one pixel, and the program updates line by line horizontally to the right across the screen. Because the calculators have only a 15MHz z80 processor and BASIC is a slow interpreted language, the code only gets one frame about every five minutes.

User input is easy: before running the program, use the Pen tool to draw your shape on the graph screen.

Adapted from my entry to a [code golf contest at the calculator forum Omnimaga](https://www.omnimaga.org/community-contests/code-golf-the-reboot-3/).

```
0
While 1
For(X,0,94
Ans/7+49seq(pxl-Test(remainder(Y,63),remainder(X+1,95)),Y,62,123
For(Y,0,62
If 1=pxl-Test(Y,X)+int(3fPart(3cosh(fPart(6ֿ¹iPart(sum(Ans,Y+1,Y+3
Pxl-Change(Y,X
End
End
End
```

### Omnimaga version (87 bytes)

This code has an additional feature: it detects if it is being run for the first time, and if randomizes the screen state. In subsequent runs it automatically continues the simulation if stopped after a frame is finished. However, it is not a competing entry because it does not wrap the screen; the cells on the outer border will always be considered dead if the graph screen is cleared beforehand.

```
0
While 1
For(X,0,93
Ans/7+49seq(pxl-Test(Y,X+1),Y,0,62
For(Y,1,61
If 2rand>isClockOn=pxl-Test(Y,X)+int(3fPart(3cosh(fPart(6ֿ¹iPart(sum(Ans,Y,Y+2
Pxl-Change(Y,X
End
End
ClockOff
End
```

This version is probably the most golfed code I have ever written, and contains some truly nasty obfuscatory optimizations:

- I use the clock state as a flag. At the start of the program, the date/time clock is enabled, and I use the value of the global isClockOn flag to determine whether it is the first iteration. After the first frame is drawn, I turn the clock off. Saves one byte over the shortest other method and about four over the obvious method.
- I store the states of the three columns next to the one being updated in a 63-element array of base-7 numbers. The 49's place holds the column to the right, the 7's place holds the middle column, and the units place holds the left column--1 for a live cell and 0 for a dead cell. Then I take the remainder mod 6 of the sum of the three numbers around the cell being modified to find the total number of live neighbor cells (it's just like the divisibility by 9 trick—in base 7, the remainder mod 6 equals the sum of the digits). Saves about 10 bytes by itself and gives the opportunity to use the next two optimizations. Example diagram (let's say there is a glider centered at a certain column at Y=45:

  ```
  Row # | Cell State       | Stored number | Mod 6 = cell count
  ...
  44      Live, Live, Live   49+7+1 = 57     3
  45      Dead, Dead, Live   49+0+0 = 49     1
  46      Dead, Live, Dead   0+7+0  = 7      1
  ...
  ```

  The center cell will stay dead, because it is surrounded by exactly five live cells.
- After each row is completed, the numbers in the array are updated by dividing the existing numbers by 7, discarding the decimal part, and adding 49 times the values of the cells in the new column. Storing all three columns each time through would be much slower and less elegant, take at least 20 more bytes, and use three lists rather than one, because the values of cells in each row must be stored before cells are updated. This is by far the smallest way to store cell positions.
- The snippet `int(3fPart(3cosh(` gives `1` when the input equals 3/6, `2` when it equals 4/6, and `0` when it equals 0, 1/6, 2/6, or 5/6. Saves about 6 bytes.

Answer (score 26):

### x86 Assembler, MSDOS, 32 bytes

[image: game of life, msdos, 32 bytes]

```
0xC5 0x24 0x20 0xB3 0x07 0x08 0x04 0xA7 0xC0 0x2D 0x05 0x91 0x02 0x41 0x5E 0x02
0x40 0xFC 0x02 0x80 0x9C 0x00 0x4B 0x75 0xF2 0x8A 0x04 0xF9 0xD2 0xD8 0xEB 0xE1
```

This code is written in x86 assembler and works in MSDOS. The binary is 32 bytes in size. You can find a [very detailed description here](http://www.sizecoding.org/wiki/Game_of_Life_32b). The visible field is 80x25. The output is directly shown on the screen in textmode, which also works as input, so you can enter patterns before you start the program. You can [download and comment](https://www.pouet.net/prod.php?which=85485) the intro, you can also [test an online version](http://twt86.co/?c=xSQgswcIBKfALQWRAkFeAkD8AoCcAEt18ooE%2BdLY6%2BE%3D).

```
lds sp,[si]
X: db 32
mov bl,7                    ; O: 3 iterations
or [si],al                  ; O: Add in new cell
cmpsw
shr byte [di],5             ; O: Shift previous value 
C: xchg cx,ax
add al,[di+bx+94]           ; O: Add in this column
add al,[si+bx-4]
add al,[si+bx+156]
dec bx                      ; O: Loop back
jnz C
mov al,[si]                 ; O: 3 = birth, 4 = stay (tricky): 
stc                         ; O: 1.00?0000x --> 0.0x100?00 (rcr 3) 
rcr al,cl                   ; O:          +---> 0.00x100?0 (rcr 4) 
jmp short X-1
```

Answer (score 23):

**Mathematica - 333**

Features:

- Interactive interface: click cells to make your patterns
- Nice grid
- Buttons: RUN, PAUSE, CLEAR

The code is below.

```
Manipulate[x=Switch[run,1,x,2,CellularAutomaton[{224,{2,{{2,2,2},{2,1,2},{2,2,2}}},
{1,1}},x],3,Table[0,{k,40},{j,40}]];EventHandler[Dynamic[tds=Reverse[Transpose[x]];
ArrayPlot[tds,Mesh->True]],{"MouseClicked":>(pos=Ceiling[MousePosition["Graphics"]];
x=ReplacePart[x,pos->1-x[[Sequence@@pos]]];)}],{{run,3,""},{1->"||",2->">",3->"X"}}]
```

[image]

If you want to get a feel how this runs, 2nd example in [**this blog**](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/04/18/how-to-make-interactive-apps-with-cdf/) is just a more elaborate version (live Fourier analysis, better interface) of the code above. Example should run right in your browser after free plugin download.

Comment: +1, nice one for having a go. Yeah that's the problem with this site, there are tonnes of old questions which one tends to miss.

Comment: @Griffin thanks for noticing it at all ;)

Answer (score 19):

## C 1063 characters

As a challenge, I did this in C using the golf-unfriendly Windows API for real time IO. If capslock is on, the simulation will run. It will stay still if capslock is off. Draw patterns with the mouse; left click revives cells and right click kills cells.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include<process.h>
#define K ][(x+80)%20+(y+80)%20*20]
#define H R.Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition
#define J R.Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState
HANDLE Q,W;char*E[3],O;Y(x,y){return E[0 K;}U(x,y,l,v){E[l K=v;}I(){E[2]=E[1];E[1]=*E;*E=E[2];memset(E[1],0,400);}A(i,j,k,l,P){while(1){Sleep(16);for(i=0;i<20;++i)for(j=0;j<20;++j){COORD a={i,j};SetConsoleCursorPosition(Q,a);putchar(E[0][i+j*20]==1?'0':' ');}if(O){for(i=0;i<20;++i)for(j=0;j<20;++j){for(k=i-1,P=0;k<i+2;++k)for(l=j-1;l<j+2;++l){P+=Y(k,l);}U(i,j,1,P==3?1:Y(i,j)==1&&P==4?1:0);}I();}}}main(T,x,y,F,D){for(x=0;x<21;++x)puts("#####################");E[0]=malloc(800);E[1]=E[0]+400;I();I();W=GetStdHandle(-10);Q=GetStdHandle(-11);SetConsoleMode(W,24);INPUT_RECORD R;F=D=O=0;COORD size={80,25};SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(Q,size);_beginthread(A,99,0);while(1){ReadConsoleInput(W,&R,1,&T);switch(R.EventType){case 1:O=R.Event.KeyEvent.dwControlKeyState&128;break;case 2:switch(R.Event.MouseEvent.dwEventFlags){case 1:x=H.X;y=H.Y;case 0:F=J&1;D=J&2;}if(F)U(x,y,0,1);if(D)U(x,y,0,0);}}}
```

The compiled EXE can be found [here](http://whff.frogbox.es/download.php?file=kwn8dgtgs3)

Edit: I've commented up the source. It's available [Here](http://pastebin.com/BrX6wgUj)

Comment: I'd love to see a commented version of this!

Comment: Sure, if I can remember what I was thinking... =p

Comment: @luserdroog Here it is http://pastebin.com/BrX6wgUj

Comment: This is just awesome.

Answer (score 16):

## J (39 characters)

```
l=:[:+/(3 4=/[:+/(,/,"0/~i:1)|.])*.1,:]
```

Based on [this APL version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9xAKttWgP4) (same algorithm, toroidal convolution).

Example usage:

```
   r =: (i.3 3) e. 1 2 3 5 8
   r
0 1 1          NB. A glider!
1 0 1
0 0 1

   R =: _1 _2 |. 5 7 {. r
   R
0 0 0 0 0 0 0  NB. Test board
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0

   l R
0 0 0 0 0 0 0  NB. Single step
0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 14):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), <s><sup>549</sup></s> <s><sup>552</sup></s> <s><sup>533</sup></s> <s><sup>421</sup></s> *420 bytes*

<sup><sub><sup><sub>Nice.</sub></sup></sub></sup>

*+3 because of a bug where cells wouldn't die if no cells came to life.*

*-19 because I made a version that was generalized to any grid size and realized that I accidentally golfed it.*

*-112 bytes because of whatnot and hornswoggling.*

*-1 byte because yes.*

```
Go0
if "<C-v><C-v><C-v><C-r>""=="<Esc>^"zC<C-v><C-v><C-v>
norm <Esc>^"yC<C-v><C-v><C-v>
en<C-v><C-v><Esc>^"xCyl'm:<C-r>z@"||"<C-v><C-r>""=="o"<C-r>y<C-v><C-v><C-v><C-a><C-r>x
<Esc>^"iC'm"myl`cyl:<C-r>z "&&<C-v><C-r>m==3<C-r>yr+<C-v>
else<C-r>z@"&&<C-v><C-r>m<2<C-r>yro<C-v>
else<C-r>z@"&&<C-v><C-r>m>3<C-r>yro<C-r>x
<Esc>^"aC`chyl:<C-r>z#"<C-r>y$h<C-r>x
mc<Esc>^"hC`cjyl:<C-r>z#"<C-v>
cal cursor(2,col('.'))<C-r>x
mc<Esc>^"jC`ckyl:<C-r>z#"<C-v>
cal cursor(line('$')-2,col('.'))<C-r>x
mc<Esc>^"kC`clyl:<C-r>z#"<C-r>y0l<C-r>x
mc<Esc>^"lC yl:<C-r>z!"<C-v>
%s/[+@]/@/g<C-v>
%s/o/ /g<C-v>
k<C-v>
else<C-r>z<BS><BS><BS>!="#" <C-r>ymc'mr0`c@h@i@k@i@l@i@l@i@j@i@j@i@h@i@h@i@k@l@a<C-r>x
@e<Esc>0"eDddmm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Y9PS8NAEMXxFnLcw1562W5qt6VqQr2JkYEIfghRGrax@bPbhRSlW/rd4yQmBeteBC8OzLLvx5s3zEfTPJnIL94Yp5QSzuOYj175IUHlb02tGSrbqWxLKYp9YpXQd@QA/Hjk/YjhxKLngux9tBSJ0FxbtZJWoZHx6ZQSHce3xNYLDFK7rB3v6P0SoTmDD63TfIWlyUrmXU6ASyY5Ui2R58jLnlNfporJ93pn6tnySho1EzdiPh@8JXorl1cV22wmJmJ@7ZiqcEqdNkdq4CphHR1j1uUufF7ASwjhphMmZO2vGg7yPG8c84AzYrUUuo5WEnIooMJWfZd9531XSFNcBtko4tnjeq11s9kwyPzubQJn@QED9qNa7OCIAcDtZv8dw3DwNwwnfuaGX7md2X9/jqvGnw)

This was fun.

The input in the TIO is (obviously) the GoL grid. You can place living tiles as `@`, and each `gg @e` in the footer is a single step, so you can add or remove them as you want to see different iterations of the board.

For each cell in the grid, it goes to all of the surrounding tiles, wrapping if it hits a `#`, and if the tile is `@` (alive) or `o` (about to die), it increments the counter. Depending on what the counter is after checking each surrounding tile, it marks the cell to live or die, or do nothing. After checking each tile in the grid, it replaces all of the `+` with `@` and all of the `o` with  . It's a bit slow, but on TIO, it's a bit faster than on my machine, which is nice.

This also works for any grid size, including rectangular grids.

Comment: Just one byte from greatness D:

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms You were saying? :P

Comment: @AaroneousMiller Niceeee

Answer (score 12):

### Mathematica, 123 characters

A very rudimentary implementation that doesn't use Mathematica's built-in CellularAutomaton function.

```
ListAnimate@NestList[ImageFilter[If[3<=Total@Flatten@#<=3+#[[2]][[2]],1,0]&,#,1]&,Image[Round/@RandomReal[1,{200,200}]],99]
```

Answer (score 10):

## Pure Bash, 244 bytes

Works on a toroidally-wrapped 36x24 universe:

```
mapfile a
for e in {0..863};{
for i in {0..8};{
[ "${a[(e/36+i/3-1)%24]:(e+i%3-1)%36:1}" == O ]&&((n++))
}
d=\ 
c=${a[e/36]:e%36:1}
[ "$c" == O ]&&((--n==2))&&d=O
((n-3))||d=O
b[e/36]+=$d
n=
}
printf -vo %s\\n "${b[@]}"
echo "$o"
exec $0<<<"$o"
```

Since this is a shell script, the method of input is congruent with other shell commands - i.e. from stdin:

```
$ ./conway.sh << EOF

   O 
    O 
  OOO 

EOF
                                                            
                                                            
  O O                                                       
   OO                                                       
   O                                                        
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            
    O                                                       
  O O                                                       
   OO
```

... etc

We can redirect input from any text source, piped through a `tr` filter to get interesting initial generations, e.g.

```
man tr | tr [:alnum:] O | ./conway.sh
```

Answer (score 10):

## ><>, 284 bytes

```
0fv   $ @$0$+1~<
+$>i:1+ ?!v:a=?^}$:@@:@{@p$1
@@:@(?$ &$>~&l1=?v:
       v    f0-e&<
v>     >   >$:{:}=?v:1+@$:@}}000102101220212280&
 ^v?=+f}}@:{{:+1$0~<
>:1-$?!v@${:}+1-${{:@}}+1-l2-[f-{{:@}}:@+$%f+${:}:@+$%$]g"!"=&+&
$@:${{~/]$r[5{{+" "+*@=3@=2:&="!"g}}@:
~~<00  v!?-4lf0]rpr[-2l~~
```

Try it at https://suppen.no/fishlanguage!

It takes the initial configuration as input, and uses a wrapping grid of the inputted size. Here's an example grid for a glider:

```
v   v
  !
   !
 !!!
v   v
```

s and `v`s are dead cells (`v`s can be used instead of  s to avoid truncation), and `!`s are alive cells. The lines don't have to be of the same size; the maximum length will be used.

Here's a Gosper glider gun: (this takes a while)

```
v                       !                          v
                      ! !
            !!      !!            !!
           !   !    !!            !!
!!        !     !   !!
!!        !   ! !!    ! !
          !     !       !
           !   !
            !!




v                                                  v
```

It stores the input in the program grid and applies changes in place, so the current state can be seen in a visual interpreter like https://suppen.no/fishlanguage

Answer (score 9):

### Scala, <strike>1181</strike> <strike>1158</strike> <strike>1128</strike> <strike>1063</strike> <strike>1018</strike> <strike>1003</strike> <strike>999</strike> <strike>992</strike> 987 characters

```
import swing._
import event._
object L extends SimpleSwingApplication{import java.awt.event._
import javax.swing._
var(w,h,c,d,r)=(20,20,20,0,false)
var x=Array.fill(w,h)(0)
def n(y:Int,z:Int)=for(b<-z-1 to z+1;a<-y-1 to y+1 if(!(a==y&&b==z)))d+=x((a+w)%w)((b+h)%h)
def top=new MainFrame with ActionListener{preferredSize=new Dimension(500,500)
menuBar=new MenuBar{contents+=new Menu("C"){contents+={new MenuItem("Go/Stop"){listenTo(this)
reactions+={case ButtonClicked(c)=>r= !r}}}}}
contents=new Component{listenTo(mouse.clicks)
reactions+={case e:MouseClicked=>var p=e.point
x(p.x/c)(p.y/c)^=1
repaint}
override def paint(g:Graphics2D){for(j<-0 to h-1;i<-0 to w-1){var r=new Rectangle(i*c,j*c,c,c)
x(i)(j)match{case 0=>g draw r
case 1=>g fill r}}}}
def actionPerformed(e:ActionEvent){if(r){var t=x.map(_.clone)
for(j<-0 to h-1;i<-0 to w-1){d=0
n(i,j)
x(i)(j)match{case 0=>if(d==3)t(i)(j)=1
case 1=>if(d<2||d>3)t(i)(j)=0}}
x=t.map(_.clone)
repaint}}
val t=new Timer(200,this)
t.start}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
import swing._
import event._

object Life extends SimpleSwingApplication
{
    import java.awt.event._
    import javax.swing._
    var(w,h,c,d,run)=(20,20,20,0,false)
    var x=Array.fill(w,h)(0)
    def n(y:Int,z:Int)=for(b<-z-1 to z+1;a<-y-1 to y+1 if(!(a==y&&b==z)))d+=x((a+w)%w)((b+h)%h)
    def top=new MainFrame with ActionListener
    {
        title="Life"
        preferredSize=new Dimension(500,500)
        menuBar=new MenuBar
        {
            contents+=new Menu("Control")
            {
                contents+={new MenuItem("Start/Stop")
                {
                    listenTo(this)
                    reactions+=
                    {
                        case ButtonClicked(c)=>run= !run
                    }
                }}
            }
        }
        contents=new Component
        {
            listenTo(mouse.clicks)
            reactions+=
            {
                case e:MouseClicked=>
                    var p=e.point
                    if(p.x<w*c)
                    {
                        x(p.x/c)(p.y/c)^=1
                        repaint
                    }
            }
            override def paint(g:Graphics2D)
            {
                for(j<-0 to h-1;i<-0 to w-1)
                {
                    var r=new Rectangle(i*c,j*c,c,c)
                    x(i)(j) match
                    {
                        case 0=>g draw r
                        case 1=>g fill r
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        def actionPerformed(e:ActionEvent)
        {
            if(run)
            {
                var t=x.map(_.clone)
                for(j<-0 to h-1;i<-0 to w-1)
                {
                    d=0
                    n(i,j)
                    x(i)(j) match
                    {
                        case 0=>if(d==3)t(i)(j)=1
                        case 1=>if(d<2||d>3)t(i)(j)=0
                    }
                }
                x=t.map(_.clone)
                repaint
            }
        }
        val timer=new Timer(200,this)
        timer.start
    }
}
```

The larger part of the code here is Swing GUI stuff. The game itself is in the `actionPerformed` method which is triggered by the `Timer`, and the helper function `n` which counts neighbours.

Usage:

Compile it with `scalac filename` and then run it with `scala L`.
Clicking a square flips it from live to dead, and the menu option starts and stops the game. If you want to change the size of the grid, change the first three values in the line: `var(w,h,c,d,r)=(20,20,20,0,false)` they are width, height and cell size (in pixels) respectively.

Comment: I found 2 golfing-improvements: `import java.awt.event._` and `contents+=m("Go",true)+=m("Stop",false)}}`, leading to 1093 characters.

Comment: @user unknown Thanks. I found a few improvements myself - down to 1063 now.

Comment: Damn you've been busy. Keep it up! I will be testing answers when a few more people post them.

Answer (score 9):

### Ruby 1.9 + SDL (<del>380</del> <del>325</del> 314)

**EDIT**: 314 characters, and fixed a bug with extra cells appearing alive on the first iteration.  Upped the grid size to 56 since the color routine only looks at the lowest 8 bits.

**EDIT**: Golfed down to 325 characters.  Grid width/height is now 28 since 28*9 is the largest you can have while still using the value as the background colour.  It also processes only one SDL event per iteration now, which obviates the inner loop completely.  Pretty tight I think!

The simulation starts paused, with all cells dead.  You can press any key to toggle pause/unpause, and click any cell to toggle it between alive and dead.  Runs an iteration every tenth of a second.

The wrapping is a bit wonky.

```ruby
require'sdl'
SDL.init W=56
R=0..T=W*W
b=[]
s=SDL::Screen.open S=W*9,S,0,0
loop{r="#{e=SDL::Event.poll}"
r['yU']?$_^=1:r[?Q]?exit: r['nU']?b[e.y/9*W+e.x/9]^=1:0
b=R.map{|i|v=[~W,-W,-55,-1,1,55,W,57].select{|f|b[(i+f)%T]}.size;v==3||v==2&&b[i]}if$_
R.map{|i|s.fillRect i%W*9,i/W*9,9,9,[b[i]?0:S]*3}
s.flip
sleep 0.1}
```

Looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of the app in action]

Fun challenge!  I welcome any improvements anybody can see.

Comment: Nice try but I can see straight away that you've gone wrong. You can't have a pattern like that in GoL. Have another read of the rules: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Rules

Comment: @Griffin I think the screenshot was taken after pausing and toggling some cells manually - I'll check the rules again, though.  Thanks!

Comment: @Griffin cant the seed pattern be in any possible configuration?

Answer (score 8):

## [Stencil](https://github.com/abrudz/Stencil), 6 bytes

*Not my favourite language, but it **is** short…*

4 code bytes plus the `∊`nlist and `T`orus flags.

```apl
3∊me
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JzUvOzPn/3/hRR1du6v//JgpGBgqGRgoGCgaPupY86l1h@qh3i5HCo965Cuk5mSmpRf/yC0oy8/OK/wM1hAAA)

Is…
 `3` 3
 `∊` a member of
 `m` the **m**oore-neighbourhood-count with self or
 `e` the moor**e**-neighbourhood-count without self
…?

Answer (score 7):

**C# - 675 chars**

I've always wanted to write a version of this program. Never knew it would only take a lazy half hour for a quick and dirty version. (Golfing it takes much longer, of course.)

```
using System.Windows.Forms;class G:Form{static void Main(){new G(25).ShowDialog();}
public G(int z){var g=new Panel[z,z];var n=new int [z,z];int x,y,t;for(int i=0;i<z;
i++)for(int j=0;j<z;j++){var p=new Panel{Width=9,Height=9,Left=i*9,Top=j*9,BackColor
=System.Drawing.Color.Tan};p.Click+=(s,a)=>p.Visible=!p.Visible;Controls.Add(g[i,j]=
p);}KeyUp+=(s,_)=>{for(int i=0;i<99;i++){for(x=0;x<z;x++)for(y=0;y<z;y++){t=0;for(int 
c=-1;c<2;c++)for(int d=-1;d<2;d++)if(c!=0||d!=0){int a=x+c,b=y+d;a=a<0?24:a>24?0:a;b=
b<0?24:b>24?0:b;t+=g[a,b].Visible?0:1;}if(t==3||t>1&&!g[x,y].Visible)n[x,y]=1;if(t<2
||t>3)n[x,y]=0;}for(x=0;x<z;x++)for(y=0;y<z;y++)g[x,y].Visible=n[x,y]<1;Update();}};}}
```

**Usage**

- Enter a starting pattern by clicking cells to turn them on (alive).
- Start the game by pressing any keyboard key.
- The game runs for 99 generations every time a key is pressed (I could have made it 9 to save a char, but that seemed too lame).

**Golfing compromises**

- You can only turn cells on with the mouse, not off, so if you make a mistake you have to restart the program.
- There are no grid lines, but that doesn't hurt playability too much.
- Update speed is proportional to CPU speed, so on very fast computers it will probably be just a blur.
- Living cells are red because "black" uses 2 more characters.
- The smallness of the cells and the fact that they don't use up all the form space are also character-saving compromises.

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript, 130

Not totally responding to the challenge, but for the record, here's a Game of Life engine in 130 bytes made by Subzey and I in 2013.

http://xem.github.io/miniGameOfLife/

```
/* Fill an array with 0's and 1's, and call g(array, width, height) to iterate */
g=function(f,c,g,d,e,b,h){g=[];e=[c+1,c,c-1,1];for(b=c*c;b--;g[b]=3==d||f[b]&&2==d,d=0)for(h in e)d+=f[b+e[h]]+f[b-e[h]];return g}
```

Comment: This seems to have some problems with the first row. For example setting `@@\n@@` (2 by 2 square in top left corner) or `.@\n.@\n.@`. (1 by 3 column)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>149</s> 144 bytes

```r
function(m)repeat{image(m)
p=apply(which(m|1,T),1,function(j)sum(m[t((j+t(which(m[1:3,1:3]|1,T)-3))%%20)+1]))
a=p==3|m&p==4;m[]=0;m[a]=1
scan()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/RCsIwDEXf@x@TBCusm09K/sK3MaTUznWsXekqKuq3z1JRfMhNAueGm7CcpdXHqTuOptO0dBenopkcWAzaaxkfPhgX08o8Se/HO1x7o3qwT8EPyAX/OQacLxZsEwGGdfxijdjVPFWb@U2NWBSiwrVoEZkkT1Q/7Sq17d42LZVJZUuCzUo6wNcyRxkiWRmDuUHJXZiuJCru1DSmjuw8mpMOX0AlpEyhRNY84cdTI8unfnno42T//0NGkC1v)

*(Note that TIO version swaps `image` for `print` so that output is visible, and reduces the grid size to 12x12 to fit into the browser window)*

Well, the challenge is still open so I guess it must be Ok to submit almost 9 years late!  And there hasn't been an `R` submission yet.

The function is called using the full starting pattern in the form of a 20x20 matrix, and it then steps forward once every time the *return* key is pressed.  Output is quite pretty using the R `image` function, or (for the same number of characters) quite ugly using only `1`s and `0`s.

[image]

Commented:

```r
game_of_life=function(m)        # Input m as starting state,
    repeat{                     # Repeat...
        image(m)                # Draw grid of current state;
        p=                      # Find p =number of live neighbours (including self):
        apply(which(m|1,T),1,   # loop over coordinates of grid...
            function(j)sum(     # getting sums of...
            m[                  # live cells at...
            t((j+               # this coordinate...
            t(which(m[1:3,1:3]|1,T)-3))
                                # plus offsets -1 to surrounding neighbours
                                # (including itself)...
            %%20)               # modulo the size of the grid (20)...
            +1]))               # plus 1 (to get 1-based coordinates)
        a=p==3|m&p==4;          # set cells with 3 live neighbours (including self)
        m[]=0;m[a]=1            # or 4 (if already alive) to 1;
                                # all others to 0.
        scan()}                 # Wait for user input before next round
```

This is a *code-golf* implementation, which admittedly rather sacrifices ease-of-input (the TIO example demonstrates how to easily set-up a glider flying across the grid).

For an extra <s>13 bytes</s> byte (145 total), it can be <s>bloated</s> improved to accept an unlimited-sized starting matrix, with the dimensions specified as an additional argument ([here](https://tio.run/##TZDRysIwDIXv@x5KghVW91/9krfwbgwpXaeVpStdRUV99lkqihfJycV3TkLifNBs92O/H1xvae7P3iQ3emDZYbTB6nQP0fkEjCKQDmG4weXozBH4oeQOpZJfzwmnMwM3CeC0Sh@sUf@1zNUWfl0jLhYdrlSLKDQFovrByyx/W25aqnLXLSkxGe0Bn/OUdEzEOkV3hUr6OF5IbaQ345AVxWFwnY0fwGSkyjep0suEb0@NokR9z6G3U/w@AAoiDeQNORzF/AI)).

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 115 bytes

Here's an easy cop-out to this:

```
ListAnimate[ArrayPlot/@CellularAutomaton[{224,{2,{{2,2,2},{2,1,2},
{2,2,2}}},{1,1}},{RandomInteger[1,{9,9}],0},90]]
```

Comment: Mathematica is fine, but as the rules state the program must allow the user to input their own patterns. This rule is intentional since a few languages allow short implementations like this but with no user interaction. Sure you can put your own array in there, but it's not gonna win.

Comment: "input" in Mathematica is mostly through the notebook interface, so I don't think "user interaction" is really possible. You just replace the RandomInteger argument to the CellularAutomaton function with whatever you want, and re-evaluate the code.

Comment: User interaction is possible. The most simplistic method I can think of right now is an array of buttons. Give it a go man.

Answer (score 6):

## Java (OpenJDK 8) - <s>400 388</s> 367 bytes

Second and (probably) Final Edit: Managed to golf an extra 21 bytes after finding these (imo) [gold](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java)[mines](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/tips-for-golfing-in-all-languages) - definitely recommend new people to read these (especially if you're going to try some of these challenges using Java).

Resulting code (probably going to end up golfing even more if I find out how to shorten those double nested for loops...):

```java
u->{int w=u.length,h=u[0].length,x,y,i,j,n;Stack<Point>r=new Stack<Point>();for(;;){for(Point c:r)u[c.x][c.y]=1;r.clear();for(x=0;x<w;++x)for(y=0;y<h;++y){boolean o=u[x][y]>0;n=o?-1:0;for(i=-2;++i<2;)for(j=-2;++j<2;)if(u[(w+x+i)%w][(h+y+j)%h]>0)++n;if(o&n>1&n<4|!o&n==3)r.add(new Point(x,y));System.out.print(u[x][y]+(y>h-2?"\n":""));}for(int[]t:u)Arrays.fill(t,0);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VXLbpwwFF2Hr3BHSmQLxoJpV2Mg6gdUqjTKirJwGCaYMPbI2AFE@fbphaHRdNW8FGUR8fI9Pj4@12dByR/4Uh1yWW7vj2J/UNqgEjBqjajod615VzPnfII3hv5UQpp/4Ym/MTy7Z46TVbyu0Q8uZO8gBNxc73iWo5uxROhBiS3KMOBJmqTIEgbwAA/cteFGZOgGWRSho13GPdBQE1la5fLOFF4R2cRP/1at13nCKz3Jpr3DyVmsI5k36BzBhO2UxoyRfvxOIMrWmtgko20Kry6NAqZpVuVcz@w28lkbNsx1WzLWHdRdWEDdkf5WKaBKpMAPCHRp7DMZqetlsPan1SJaroAqwhWbVpenuhxrscM2wY3buoJcNmmCC7dzS3JZgApxXcmAoK5kHFzJ8NvvLzCMoq9EU77d4rG1yT@G5glhm642@Z4qa@hBj/Dsx8VdXCxX14tfcrFeLIA5TLbGUzdrS07h0p2oKmw8H6aHIzuFcLC3FYQwZzHFtYcw8cbABncQGSfAOoVpaTZZmtPse997g2vwnIuLUf795YLXygXPFfyfu@BRIjgbv0gueEp7z3X38ZN9ctvvKBe8bbMfW87/lPuUe5Qb5j/@cPwD)

(Original post starts here.)

I actually thought for a moment that I would be able to at least challenge the best Python answer with my (arguably limited) knowledge of Java lol...It was a challenge I nevertheless enjoyed partaking in (despite having joined the party perhaps just a little bit late...)

There's not much to it really - basic explanation as follows (ungolfed):

```java
/*
 * Explanation of each variable's usage:
 * w=height* of array
 * h=width* of array
 * x=y* coord of point in array
 * y=x* coord of point in array
 * i and j are counters for calculating the neighbours around a point in the array
 * n=neighbour counter
 * r=temporary array to store the cells from the current generation
 * u=the 2d array used for all the calculations (parameter from lambda expression)
 * c=temporary variable used to help populate the 2d array
 * o=boolean variable that stores the value of whether the cell is alive or not
 */
u-> // start of lambda statement with u as parameter (no need for brackets as it's only one parameter being passed)
{
    int w=u.length,h=u[0].length,x,y,i,j,n; // defines all the necessary integer variables;
    Stack<Point>r=new Stack<Point>(); // same with the only array list needed (note how I only use two data structures);
    for(;;) // notice how this is still an infinite loop but using a for loop;
    {
        for(Point c:r)u[c.x][c.y]=1; //for every point in the "previous" generation, add that to the 2D array as a live (evil?) cell;
        r.clear(); // clears the array list to be populated later on
        for(x=0;x<w;++x) // a pair of nested for loops to iterate over every cell of the 2D array;
        {
            for(y=0;y<h;++y)
            {
                // sets o to be the presence of a live cell at (x,y) then uses said value in initialising the neighbour counter;
                boolean o=u[x][y]>1;n=o?-1:0;
                for(i=-2;++i<2;) // another pair of nested for loops - this one iterates over a 3x3 grid around *each* cell of the 2D array;
                {                // this includes wrap-around (note the modulus sign in the if statement below);
                    for(j=-2;++j<2;)
                    {
                        if(u[(w+x+i)%w][(h+y+j)%h]>0)++n; // this is where the first interesting thing lies - the bit which makes wrap-around a reality;
                    }
                }
                if(o&n>1&n<4|!o&n==3)r.add(new Point(x,y)); // this is the second interesting bit of my code - perhaps more so as I use bitwise operators to calculate the number of neighbours (x,y) has;
                                                            // (since I'm technically dealing with 0s and 1s, it's not a total misuse of them imo);
                System.out.print(u[x][y]+(y>h-2?"\n":""));  // that extra part of the print statement adds a newline if we reached the end of the current 'line';
            }
        }
        // since the information about the new generation is now in the array list, this array can be emptied out, ready to receive said info on the new generation;
        for(int[]t:u)Arrays.fill(t,0);
    }
} // end of lambda statement
```

(more information about lambda statements in Java 8 [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html))

Yes, there's a catch with my approach.

As most of you probably noticed, my golfed code as it currently stands will loop forever. To prevent this, a counter can be introduced at the top and used in the while loop to only display `n` (in this case, 5) iterations as follows (notice the new `b` variable added):

```java
u->{int b=0,w=u.length,h=u[0].length,x,y,i,j,n;Stack<Point>r=new Stack<Point>();for(;++b<6;){for(Point c:r)u[c.x][c.y]=1;r.clear();for(x=0;x<w;++x)for(y=0;y<h;++y){boolean o=u[x][y]>0;n=o?-1:0;for(i=-2;++i<2;)for(j=-2;++j<2;)if(u[(w+x+i)%w][(h+y+j)%h]>0)++n;if(o&n>1&n<4|!o&n==3)r.add(new Point(x,y));System.out.print(u[x][y]+(y>h-2?"\n":""));}for(int[]t:u)Arrays.fill(t,0);}}
```

Additionally, a few points worth mentioning. This program does not check if the input is correct and will, therefore, fail with (most likely) an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`; as such, make sure to check that the input is valid by completely filling in a part of an array (skewered arrays will throw the exception mentioned above). Also, the board as it currently is looks 'fluid' - that is, there is no separation between one generation and the next. If you wish to add that in to double-check that the generations being produced are indeed valid, an extra `System.out.println();` needs to be added just before `for(int[]t:u)Arrays.fill(t,0);` (see this [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VbNbpwwGDyHp3BXSmQL1oJtT2sg6gNUqrTKiXJwWDaYsPbK2AFEefbtB0uibS9N2ijKIeLPM4yH@TQXSv7Al@qQy3J7fxT7g9IGlcBRa0RFv2rNu5o55y94Y@h3JaT5nZ70G8Oze@Y4WcXrGn3jQvYOQqDN9Y5nOboZIUIPSmxRhoFP0iRFljCgB7jgrA03IkM3yKIIHe0y7kGGmsjSKpd3pvCKyCZ@@ohar/OEV3qSTd8Op2SxjmTeoHMGE7ZTGjNG@vE5kShba2KTjLYp3Lo0CpimWZVzPavbyGdt2DDXbcmIO8BdWADuSH@rFEglUpAHDLo09pmM1PUyWPvTbhEtVyAV4YpNu8sTLkcsdtgmuHFbV5DLJk1w4XZuSS4LcCGuKxkI1JWMgysZfvn5CZZR9JloyrdbPI425ccwPCFs09Um31NlDT3okZ7zuLiLi@XqevFDLtaLBSiHP6WVnCedqjBrS06N052oKmw8H/YMR3Zq5mBvK2hmLmjqcA8N440BqzvokRNQnRq2NJtyzhX3ve@9wjF4zsXFaP/2dsH/2gUvNfxbuuDJIjhb/5Nd8JzxXpru/Tf77LHf0C543WHft53/Yfdh92Q3zL8Bw/EX) for clarity). And last, but not least, given that this is my first code golf, any feedback is greatly appreciated :)

Old code from previous 388 byte answer:

```java
u->{int w=u.length,h=u[0].length,x,y,i,j,n;ArrayList<Point>r=new ArrayList<Point>();while(true){for(Point c:r)u[c.x][c.y]=1;r.clear();for(x=0;x<w;++x){for(y=0;y<h;++y){boolean o=u[x][y]==1;n=o?-1:0;for(i=-2;++i<2;)for(j=-2;++j<2;)if(u[(w+x+i)%w][(h+y+j)%h]==1)++n;if(o&n>1&n<4|!o&n==3)r.add(new Point(x,y));System.out.print(u[x][y]);}System.out.println();}for(int[]t:u)Arrays.fill(t,0);}}
```

And from the initial 400 byte answer:

```java
int w=35,h=20,x,y,i,j,n;ArrayList<Point>l=new ArrayList<Point>(),r;while(true){int[][]u=new int[w][h];for(Point c:l)u[c.x][c.y]=1;r=new ArrayList<Point>();for(x=0;x<w;++x){for(y=0;y<h;++y){boolean o=u[x][y]==1;n=o?-1:0;for(i=-2;++i<2;)for(j=-2;++j<2;)if(u[(w+x+i)%w][(h+y+j)%h]==1)++n;if(o&n>1&n<4|!o&n==3)r.add(new Point(x,y));System.out.print(u[x][y]);}System.out.println();}l.clear();l.addAll(r);}
```

Comment: Amazing first post, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks, I'm definitely going to be doing more of these - they're fun :)

Comment: Join us, we have Dennis. Also, this is not a complete program nor a function, which it needs to be, IIRC.

Comment: Oh right forgot the 'program' part :P Editing that in in a bit.

Comment: It can just be a function too.

Comment: Woo hoo finally fixed it. That should do it right?

Comment: Yeah, again, **amazing** job considering this is your first golf here.

Comment: Thanks :) Just one final question - should I remove all the text with the strikethrough formatting or should I leave it for people who may view this in the future and can compare between my submissions (and what was wrong with the first one which can serve as a lesson for other people)?

Comment: You should probably remove the strucken text if you have **that** much of it.

Comment: There we go - finally got around to change and improve this :)

Answer (score 6):

## brainfuck (715 bytes)

```
[life.b -- John Horton Conway's Game of Life
(c) 2021 Daniel B. Cristofani
http://brainfuck.org/]

>>>->+++++[>+>++++<<-]+>>[[>>>+<<<-]>+++++>+>>+[<<+>>>>>+<<<-]<-]>>>>[
  [>>>+>+<<<<-]+++>>+[<+>>>+>+<<<-]>>[>[[>>>+<<<-]<]<<++>+>>>>>>-]<-
]+++>+>[[-]<+<[>+++++++++++++++++<-]<+]>>[
  [+++++++++.-------->>>]+[-<<<]>>>[>>,----------[>]<]<<[
    <<<[
      >--[<->>+>-<<-]<[[>>>]+>-[+>>+>-]+[<<<]<-]>++>[<+>-]
      >[[>>>]+[<<<]>>>-]+[->>>]<-[++>]>[------<]>+++[<<<]>
    ]<
  ]>[
    -[+>>>-]+>>>>>>[<+<<]>->>[
      >[->+>+++>>++[>>>]+++<<<++<<<++[>>>]>>>]<<<[>[>>>]+>>>]
      <<<<<<<[<<++<+[-<<<+]->++>>>++>>>++<<<<]<<<+[-<<<+]+>->>->>
    ]<<+<<+<<<+<<-[+<+<<-]+<+[
      ->+>[-<-<<[<<<]>[>>[>>>]<<+<[<<<]>-]]
      <[<[<[<<<]>+>>[>>>]<<-]<[<<<]]>>>->>>[>>>]+>
    ]>+[-<<[-]<]-[
      [>>>]<[<<[<<<]>>>>>+>[>>>]<-]>>>[>[>>>]<<<<+>[<<<]>>-]>
    ]<<<<<<[---<-----[-[-[<->>+++<+++++++[-]]]]<+<+]>
  ]>>
]

[Type e.g. "be" to toggle the fifth cell in the second row, "q" to quit,
or a bare linefeed to advance one generation.]
```

Answer (score 6):

## Java/Processing, <del>289</del> 287 bytes

This is my first submission to Code Golf.

- a grid of 100x100 that wraps around
- draw custom patterns with mouse

```java
void draw(){if(mousePressed){line(pmouseX,pmouseY,mouseX,mouseY);return;}
loadPixels();PImage p=get();for(int i=0,x=0,y=0,n=0,w=100,h=100;i<w*h;i++,
x=i%w,y=i/w,n=0){for(int j=0;j<9;j++)n+=p.get((x+j%3-1+w)%w,(y+j/3-1+h)%h)
/color(0);if(n!=4)pixels[i]=color(n==3?0:255);}updatePixels();}
```

[image: CodeGolf submission Conway Game of Life]

**Ungolfed version**

```java
void draw() {
  if (mousePressed) {
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
    return;
  }
  loadPixels();
  PImage p=get();
  for (int i=0, x=0, y=0, n=0, w=100, h=100; i<w*h; i++, x=i%w, y=i/w, n=0) {
    for (int j=0; j<9; j++) 
      n+=p.get((x+j%3-1+w)%w, (y+j/3-1+h)%h)/color(0);
    if (n!=4)
      pixels[i]=color(n==3?0:255);
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: The `n==3` part of `n==3|n!=4` seems to be redundant, which means you can get away with just the condition of `n!=4`

Answer (score 5):

#### GW-BASIC, <strike>1086</strike> 1035 bytes (tokenised)

In tokenised form, this is 1035 bytes. (The ASCII form is, of course, a bit longer.) You get the tokenised form by using the `SAVE"life` command without appending `",a` in the interpreter.

```
10 DEFINT A-Z:DEF SEG=&HB800:KEY OFF:COLOR 7,0:CLS:DEF FNP(X,Y)=PEEK((((Y+25)MOD 25)*80+((X+80)MOD 80))*2)
20 X=0:Y=0
30 LOCATE Y+1,X+1,1
40 S$=INKEY$:IF S$=""GOTO 40
50 IF S$=CHR$(13)GOTO 150
60 IF S$=" "GOTO 130
70 IF S$=CHR$(0)+CHR$(&H48)THEN Y=(Y-1+25)MOD 25:GOTO 30
80 IF S$=CHR$(0)+CHR$(&H50)THEN Y=(Y+1)MOD 25:GOTO 30
90 IF S$=CHR$(0)+CHR$(&H4B)THEN X=(X-1+80)MOD 80:GOTO 30
100 IF S$=CHR$(0)+CHR$(&H4D)THEN X=(X+1)MOD 80:GOTO 30
110 IF S$="c"THEN CLS:GOTO 20
120 GOTO 40
130 Z=PEEK((Y*80+X)*2):IF Z=42 THEN Z=32ELSE Z=42
140 POKE(Y*80+X)*2,Z:GOTO 40
150 LOCATE 1,1,0:ON KEY(1)GOSUB 320:KEY(1) ON
160 V!=TIMER+.5:FOR Y=0 TO 24:FOR X=0 TO 79:N=0
170 Z=FNP(X-1,Y-1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
180 Z=FNP(X,Y-1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
190 Z=FNP(X+1,Y-1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
200 Z=FNP(X-1,Y):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
210 Z=FNP(X+1,Y):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
220 Z=FNP(X-1,Y+1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
230 Z=FNP(X,Y+1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
240 Z=FNP(X+1,Y+1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
250 Z=PEEK((Y*80+X)*2):IF Z=32 THEN IF N=3 THEN Z=43
260 IF Z=42 THEN IF N<2 OR N>3 THEN Z=46
270 POKE(Y*80+X)*2,Z:NEXT:NEXT:FOR Y=0 TO 24:FOR X=0 TO 79:Z=PEEK((Y*80+X)*2):IF Z=46 THEN Z=32
280 IF Z=43 THEN Z=42
290 POKE(Y*80+X)*2,Z:NEXT:NEXT
300 IF TIMER<V!GOTO 300
310 IF INKEY$=""GOTO 160
320 SYSTEM
```

This is the maximum-golfed version, but still featureful: upon starting, you get an editor, in which you can move with the cursor keys; space toggles bacteria on/off on the current field, `c` clears the screen, Return starts game mode.

Here follows a less-obfuscated version, which also sets an initial game board with two structures (a circulary-rotating thing and a glider):

```
1000 REM Conway's Game of Life
1001 REM -
1002 REM Copyright (c) 2012 Thorsten "mirabilos" Glaser
1003 REM All rights reserved. Published under The MirOS Licence.
1004 REM -
1005 DEFINT A-Z:DEF SEG=&hB800
1006 KEY OFF:COLOR 7,0:CLS
1007 DEF FNP(X,Y)=PEEK((((Y+25) MOD 25)*80+((X+80) MOD 80))*2)
1010 PRINT "Initial setting mode, press SPACE to toggle, RETURN to continue"
1020 PRINT "Press C to clear the board, R to reset. OK? Press a key then."
1030 WHILE INKEY$="":WEND
1050 CLS
1065 DATA 3,3,4,3,5,3,6,3,7,3,8,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,4,7,4,8,4
1066 DATA 10,3,10,4,10,5,10,6,10,7,10,8,11,3,11,4,11,5,11,6,11,7,11,8
1067 DATA 11,10,10,10,9,10,8,10,7,10,6,10,11,11,10,11,9,11,8,11,7,11,6,11
1068 DATA 4,11,4,10,4,9,4,8,4,7,4,6,3,11,3,10,3,9,3,8,3,7,3,6
1069 DATA 21,0,22,1,22,2,21,2,20,2,-1,-1
1070 RESTORE 1065
1080 READ X,Y
1090 IF X=-1 GOTO 1120
1100 POKE (Y*80+X)*2,42
1110 GOTO 1080
1120 X=0:Y=0
1125 LOCATE Y+1,X+1,1
1130 S$=INKEY$
1140 IF S$="" GOTO 1130
1150 IF S$=CHR$(13) GOTO 1804
1160 IF S$=" " GOTO 1240
1170 IF S$=CHR$(0)+CHR$(&h48) THEN Y=(Y-1+25) MOD 25:GOTO 1125
1180 IF S$=CHR$(0)+CHR$(&h50) THEN Y=(Y+1) MOD 25:GOTO 1125
1190 IF S$=CHR$(0)+CHR$(&h4B) THEN X=(X-1+80) MOD 80:GOTO 1125
1200 IF S$=CHR$(0)+CHR$(&h4D) THEN X=(X+1) MOD 80:GOTO 1125
1210 IF S$="c" THEN CLS:GOTO 1120
1220 IF S$="r" GOTO 1050
1225 IF S$=CHR$(27) THEN END
1230 GOTO 1130
1240 Z=PEEK((Y*80+X)*2)
1250 IF Z=42 THEN Z=32 ELSE Z=42
1260 POKE (Y*80+X)*2,Z
1270 GOTO 1130
1804 LOCATE 1,1,0
1900 ON KEY(1) GOSUB 2300
1910 KEY(1) ON
2000 V!=TIMER+.5
2010 FOR Y=0 TO 24
2020  FOR X=0 TO 79
2030   N=0
2040   Z=FNP(X-1,Y-1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
2050   Z=FNP(X  ,Y-1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
2060   Z=FNP(X+1,Y-1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
2070   Z=FNP(X-1,Y  ):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
2080   Z=FNP(X+1,Y  ):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
2090   Z=FNP(X-1,Y+1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
2100   Z=FNP(X  ,Y+1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
2110   Z=FNP(X+1,Y+1):IF Z=42 OR Z=46 THEN N=N+1
2120   Z=PEEK((Y*80+X)*2)
2130   IF Z=32 THEN IF N=3 THEN Z=43
2140   IF Z=42 THEN IF N<2 OR N>3 THEN Z=46
2150   POKE (Y*80+X)*2,Z
2160  NEXT X
2170 NEXT Y
2200 FOR Y=0 TO 24
2210  FOR X=0 TO 79
2220   Z=PEEK((Y*80+X)*2)
2230   IF Z=46 THEN Z=32
2240   IF Z=43 THEN Z=42
2250   POKE (Y*80+X)*2,Z
2260  NEXT X
2270 NEXT Y
2280 IF TIMER<V! GOTO 2280
2290 IF INKEY$="" GOTO 2000
2300 SYSTEM
```

I wrote this in 15 minutes while bored and waiting for a friend, who was code-golfing with his “apprentice” for Conway’s Game of Life at the same time.

It functions like this: It immediately uses the 80x25 text mode screen buffer (change the initial `DEF SEG` to use `&hB000` if you’re on a Hercules graphics card; these settings work with Qemu and (slower) dosbox). An asterisk `*` is a bacterium.

It works two-pass: first, birthplaces are marked with `+` and death marks its targets with `.`. In the second pass, `+` and `.` are replaced with `*` and  , respectively.

The `TIMER` thing is to make it wait for half a second after each round, in case your Qemu host is very fast ☺

I’m not hoping for a shortest-wins price here but for a coolness one, especially considering the initial board setup. I’ve also got a version where the game engine was replaced by assembly code, in case you’re interested…

Comment: Considering you incremented your labels by 1 on the non-golfed version, is it possible to do the same on the golfed version? (i.e., `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.) Or do the line numbers not count?

Comment: line numbers, when tokenised, count as word (16 bit), if I’m not totally mistaken

Comment: Okay then, guess I must've been thinking of some other BASIC dialect then.

Comment: @Zacharý Click [on “GW-BASIC tokenised program format” then on “Program format” here](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/viewchm.php/hs/gwbasic.chm/) to see that, indeed, line numbers are constantly two bytes, and for more in-depth details on the token format.

Answer (score 4):

## J, 45

I thought I'd give J a try. It's not particularly well golfed yet, but I'll give it another try soon.

```
(]+.&(3&=)+)+/((4&{.,(_4&{.))(>,{,~<i:1))&|.
```

Example:

```
   f =: 5 5 $ 0 1 0 0 0   0 0 1 0 0   1 1 1 0 0   0 0 0 0 0    0 0 0 0 0
   f
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
   f (]+.&(3&=)+)+/((4&{.,(_4&{.))(>,{,~<i:1))&|. f
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 4):

## **Processing** <strike>536</strike> 532

```
int h=22,t=24,i,j;int[][]w=new int[t][t],b=new int[t][t];int[]q={1,0,-1};void draw(){if(t<9){clear();for(i=2;i<h;i++){for(j=2;j<h;j++)w[i][j]=b[i][j];w[i][1]=w[i][21];w[i][h]=w[i][2];w[1][i]=w[21][i];w[h][i]=w[2][i];}for(i=1;i<23;i++)for(j=1;j<23;j++){t=-w[i][j];for(int s:q)for(int d:q)t+=w[i+s][j+d];b[i][j]=w[i][j]>0&(t<2|t>3)?0:t==3?1:b[i][j];}a();}}void keyPressed(){t=0;}void mousePressed(){int i=mouseX/5+2,j=mouseY/5+2;w[i][j]=b[i][j]=1;a();}void a(){for(i=0;i<h-2;i++)for(j=0;j<h-2;j++)if(w[i+2][j+2]==1)rect(i*5,j*5,5,5);}
```

I believe this satisfies all of the requirements.

Ungolfed:

```
int h=22,t=24,i,j;
int[][]w=new int[t][t],b=new int[t][t];
int[]q={1,0,-1};
void draw(){
  if(t<9){
  clear();
  for(i=2;i<h;i++){
    for(j=2;j<h;j++)
      w[i][j]=b[i][j];  
    w[i][1]=w[i][21];
    w[i][h]=w[i][2];
    w[1][i]=w[21][i];
    w[h][i]=w[2][i];
  }
  for(i=1;i<23;i++)
    for(j=1;j<23;j++){
      t=-w[i][j];
      for(int s:q)
        for(int d:q)
          t+=w[i+s][j+d];        
      b[i][j]=w[i][j]>0&(t<2|t>3)?0:t==3?1:b[i][j];  
  }
  a();
}
}
void keyPressed(){
  t=0;
}
void mousePressed(){
  int i=mouseX/5+2,j=mouseY/5+2;
  w[i][j]=b[i][j]=1;
  a();
}
void a(){
  for(i=0;i<h-2;i++)
    for(j=0;j<h-2;j++)
      if(w[i+2][j+2]==1)
        rect(i*5,j*5,5,5);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <strike>218</strike> <strike>216</strike> <strike>211</strike> 202 bytes

```
$,=$/;$~=AX3AAAx76;$b=pack('(A79)23',<>)x6;{print unpack'(a79)23a0',$b;select$v,$v,$v,0.1;$b=pack'(A)*',unpack'((x7a/(x13)X4Ax!18)1817@0)4',pack'((a*)17xx!18)*',unpack"x1737(AA$~Ax$~AA$~@)2222",$b;redo}
```

(No newline at the end of this code.)

Reads the starting pattern from standard input, as a text file where live cells are represented as `1`, dead cells represented as a space, lines are separated by a newline.  The input shall not have characters other than these.  Lines can be variable length, and will be padded or truncated to exactly 79 wide.  Example input is a glider gun:

```
                                  1
                                1 1
                      11      11            11
                     1   1    11            11
          11        1     1   11
          11        1   1 11    1 1
                    1     1       1
                     1   1
                      11









                                         11
                                         1
                                          111
                                            1
```

As the program runs Game of Life, every state is dumped to the standard output in a format similar to the input, then delays 0.1 seconds.  The delay can be customized by changing the fourth argument of the select call.

The game board is hard-coded to size 79x23.  It is wrapped in a torus: if you leave the board on the bottom, you end up at the top; if you leave on the right side, you end up at the left side but shifted one row down.

Here's an alternate version that doesn't read any input and starts from a random board:

```
$,=$/;$/=AX3AAAx76;$b=pack("(A)*",map{rand 3<1}0..1816)x6;{print unpack'(a79)23a0',$b;select$v,$v,$v,0.1;$b=pack'(A)*',unpack'((x7a/(x13)X4Ax!18)1817@0)4',pack'((a*)17xx!18)*',unpack"x1737(AA$/Ax$/AA$/@)2222",$b;redo}
```

This code is derived from [an obfuscated game of life perl program I wrote years ago](http://www.perlmonks.com/?node_id=1008395).  I have changed it a lot to make the board toroidal and golf the code.

This is probably not the shortest method to implement Game of Life in perl, but it's one of the less comprehensible ones.

> The board is stored in `$b` as a string of `'1'` and `' '`, one for each cell, only the whole thing is repeated at least three times.  The third unpack call extracts 17 values for each cell: there's one for the cell itself and two for each of the eight neighboring cells, in an arbitrary order, and each value is `'1'` or an empty string.  The cell should be live in the next iteration iff the number of `'1'` values among these 17 values is 5, 6, or 7.  The third pack call concatenates these 17 values to a 18 character wide field left aligned and padded with nul bytes on the right.  The second unpack call takes such a 18 wide field, dispatches on the character at position 7, unpacks the space from position 17 if it's a `'1'`, or unpacks the character from position 4 otherwise.  This result is exactly the value the cell should have in the next generation.

Answer (score 4):

## C  <del>811</del> <del>806</del> <del>800</del> <del>783</del> 753 Bytes

```c
#define S(y) SDL_##y;
#define s unsigned
#define u s char
#define _ g[i*256+j]
#define L for(s i=0;i<256;i++)for(s j=0;j<256;j++)
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
struct __attribute__((__packed__)){u l:1;u n:7;}g[1<<16];main(u k, u** v){S(Window*w)S(Renderer*r)S(Texture*t)uint32_t p[1<<16];S(CreateWindowAndRenderer(256,256,0,&w,&r))t=S(CreateTexture(r,372645892,1,256,256))read(open(v[1],0),g,1<<16);for(;;){L _.n=g[((u)(i-1))*256+((u)(j-1))].l+g[((u)(i-1))*256+j].l+g[((u)(i-1))*256+(u)(j+1)].l+g[(i<<8)+(u)(j-1)].l+g[(i*256)+(u)(j+1)].l+g[((u)(i+1))*256+((u)(j-1))].l+g[((u)(i+1))*256+j].l+g[((u)(i+1))*256+(u)(j+1)].l;L _.l=(_.n==3||_.l&&_.n==2);for(s i=0;i<1<<16;i++){p[i]=(g[i].l<<7);}S(UpdateTexture(t,0,p,1024))S(RenderCopy(r,t,0,0))S(RenderPresent(r))}}
```

this one might be "overkill" for being 255x255 instead of just 20, but this way I didn't have to bound check and could just cast instead

### To compile & run:

```sh
cc gol.c -lsdl2
./a.out /path/to/seed
```

### To seed it:

Specify a file, the contents of the file will be read into the graph, and only the least-significant bit actually matters,
I would recommend using /dev/urandom

Answer (score 4):

## [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), 23 bytes

```
ffplay -f lavfi -i life
```

FFmpeg pulled a Mathematica here. This trick uses Libavfilter, a high-level library for video processing. It comes with a builtin filter for GoL.

Comment: I figured out how to pass options to the filter: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide

`ffplay -f lavfi -i life=death_color=red:life_color=black:r=60:rule=B36/S23`

This is High Life (B36/S23) in red at 60FPS, which has more interesting behavior on randomly generated boards IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Scala - 799 chars

Run as a script. A mouse click on a square toggles it on or off and any key starts or stops generation.

```
import java.awt.Color._
import swing._
import event._
import actors.Actor._
new SimpleSwingApplication{var(y,r,b)=(200,false,Array.fill(20,20)(false))
lazy val u=new Panel{actor{loop{if(r){b=Array.tabulate(20,20){(i,j)=>def^(i:Int)= -19*(i min 0)+(i max 0)%20
var(c,n,r)=(0,b(i)(j),-1 to 1)
for(x<-r;y<-r;if x!=0||y!=0){if(b(^(i+x))(^(j+y)))c+=1}
if(n&&(c<2||c>3))false else if(!n&&c==3)true else n}};repaint;Thread.sleep(y)}}
focusable=true
preferredSize=new Dimension(y,y)
listenTo(mouse.clicks,keys)
reactions+={case e:MouseClicked=>val(i,j)=(e.point.x/10,e.point.y/10);b(i)(j)= !b(i)(j)case _:KeyTyped=>r= !r}
override def paintComponent(g:Graphics2D){g.clearRect(0,0,y,y);g.setColor(red)
for(x<-0 to 19;y<-0 to 19 if b(x)(y))g.fillRect(x*10,y*10,9,9)}}
def top=new Frame{contents=u}}.main(null)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab (152)

```
b=uint8(rand(20)<0.2)
s=@(m)imfilter(m,[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1],'circular')
p=@(m,n)uint8((n==3)|(m&(n==2)))
while 1
imshow(b)
drawnow
b=p(b,s(b))
end
```

I dont have Matlab installed right now to test it, I just golfed the code that I wrote a few years ago.
Ungolfed:

```
%% initialize
Bsize = 20;
nsteps = 100;
board = uint8(rand(Bsize)<0.2); % fill 20% of the board
boardsum = @(im) imfilter(im,[1 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 1], 'circular');
step = @(im, sumim) uint8((sumim==3) | (im & (sumim==2)) );

%% run
for i = 1:nsteps
    imshow(kron(board,uint8(ones(4))), [])
    drawnow
    ss(p,i) = sum(board(:));
    board = step(board, boardsum(board));
end
```

- Boardsize is hardcoded but can be anything
- wraps around
- for user input one can change the inital board either by hardcoding another matrix or using the variable editor. Not pretty, but it works
- 20 chars can be saved if the graphical output is skipped, the board will still be printed as text at every iteration. One-pixel cells which change every millisecond are not very useful anyway

Comment: works in R2014a, just tested

Answer (score 3):

## Lua + [LÖVE/Love2D](https://love2d.org/), 653 bytes

```lua
l=love f=math.floor t={}s=25 w=20 S=1 for i=1,w do t[i]={}for j=1,w do t[i][j]=0 end end e=0 F=function(f)loadstring("for i=1,#t do for j=1,#t[i]do "..f.." end end")()end function l.update(d)if S>0 then return end e=e+d if e>.2 then e=0 F("c=0 for a=-1,1 do for b=-1,1 do if not(a==0 and b==0)then c=c+(t[((i+a-1)%w)+1][((j+b-1)%w)+1]>0 and 1 or 0)end end end g=t[i][j]t[i][j]=(c==3 or(c==2 and g==1))and(g==1 and 5 or-1)or(g==1 and 4 or 0)")F("t[i][j]=t[i][j]%2")end end function l.draw()F("l.graphics.rectangle(t[i][j]==1 and'fill'or'line',i*s,j*s,s,s)")end function l.mousepressed(x,y)S=0 o,p=f(x/s),f(y/s)if t[o]and t[o][p]then t[o][p]=1 S=1 end end
```

or spaced out:

```lua
l=love
f=math.floor
t={}s=25
w=20
S=1
for i=1,w do
    t[i]={}
    for j=1,w do
        t[i][j]=0
    end
end
e=0
F=function(f)
    loadstring("for i=1,#t do for j=1,#t[i] do  "..f.." end end")()
end
function l.update(d)
    if S>0 then
        return
    end
    e=e+d
    if e>.2 then
        e=0
        F([[
        c=0
        for a=-1,1 do
            for b=-1,1 do
                if not(a==0 and b==0)then
                    c=c+(t[((i+a-1)%w)+1][((j+b-1)%w)+1]>0 and 1 or 0)
                end
            end
        end
        g=t[i][j]
        t[i][j]=(c==3 or(c==2 and g==1))and(g==1 and 5 or-1) or (g==1 and 4 or 0)]])
        F("t[i][j]=t[i][j]%2")
    end
end
function l.draw()
    F("l.graphics.rectangle(t[i][j]==1 and'fill'or'line',i*s,j*s,s,s)") end
function l.mousepressed(x,y)
    S=0
    o,p=f(x/s),f(y/s)
    if t[o]and t[o][p] then
        t[o][p]=1
        S=1
    end
end
```

Click on the field to add living cells. Click outside of the field to run it.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/repls/RespectfulLoudPhase)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Batch 1131 bytes

Golfed version of my answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/242839/224870)

- requires windows 10 with virtual terminal support
- version has been modified to allow for input of pattern if called with custom args for Y and X axis.

```bat
@Echo off&Set $=Set &Cls
For /f %%e in ('echo prompt $E^|cmd')Do %$%\E=%%e
%$%F=For /l %%# in (&Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
%$%/AY=20,X=20&If not "%~2"=="" %$%/AY=%1,X=%2,C=1
%F:#=n%0 1 9)Do %F:#=s%0 1 1)Do %$%#%%n%%s=0
%$%/A#21=1,#30=1,#31=1,D=1001001010
%$%t}=&%F:#=y%1 1 %Y%)Do %F:#=x%1 1 %X%)Do For /f %%v in ('%$%/a !random! %%9+1')Do (
%$%/An.%%y;%%x=%%y-1,e.%%y;%%x=%%x+1,s.%%y;%%x=%%y+1,w.%%y;%%x=%%x-1
If %%y==1 %$%n.%%y;%%x=%Y%
If %%y==%Y% %$%s.%%y;%%x=1
If %%x==1 %$%w.%%y;%%x=%X%
If %%x==%X% %$%e.%%y;%%x=1
%$%%%y;%%xN=}!n.%%y;%%x!;%%x+}%%y;!e.%%y;%%x!+}!s.%%y;%%x!;%%x+}%%y;!w.%%y;%%x!+}!n.%%y;%%x!;!e.%%y;%%x!
%$%%%y;%%xN=!%%y;%%xN!+}!n.%%y;%%x!;!w.%%y;%%x!+}!s.%%y;%%x!;!e.%%y;%%x!+}!s.%%y;%%x!;!w.%%y;%%x!
If .!c!==. (%$%t}=!t}!}%%y;%%xH!D:~%%v,1!,)Else (<nul %$%/p=%\E%[%%y;%%xH?&Title %%y;%%x 0/1:
For /f %%V in ('Choice /N /C:01')Do (%$%q=%%V&%$%t}=!t}!}%%y;%%xH%%V,&<nul %$%/p=%\E%[%%y;%%xH!q!)))
%F% in ()Do (%$%O=!t}:}=%\E%[!
Echo(!O:,=!%\E%[?25l
%$%/A!t}:H==!1&%$%t}=
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=}=" %%1 in ('%$%}')Do (%$%/A[n]=!%%1N!
For %%s in ("![n]!%%2")Do %$%t}=!t}!}%%1H!#%%~s!,))
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 589 bytes

Mouse buttons: left - put a cell, right - remove a cell, middle - start/stop.

```
from Tkinter import*
import copy
z=range
F=50
T=Tk()
S=9
f=[F*[0]for i in'7'*F]
c=Canvas(T,width=S*F,height=S*F)
c.pack()
def p(x,y,a):f[y][x]=f[y][x]or c.create_oval(x*S,y*S,x*S+S,y*S+S)if a else c.delete(f[y][x])
r=1
def R(e):global r;r=1-r
exec("c.bind('<Button-%i>',lambda e:p(e.x/S,e.y/S,%i));"*2%(1,1,3,0))
c.bind('<Button-2>',R)
def L():
 T.after(99,L)
 if r:return
 g=copy.deepcopy(f)
 for y in z(F):
	for x in z(F):
	 n=8
	 for j in z(-1,2):
		for i in z(-1,2):
		 if i or j:n-=not g[(y+j)%F][(x+i)%F]
	 if 1<n<4:
		if n==3and not g[y][x]:p(x,y,1)
	 else:p(x,y,0)
L()
T.mainloop()
```

And here is a version where you can drag mouse to draw. Graphics are a bit more pleasant.

```
from Tkinter import*
import copy
z=range
F=50
T=Tk()
S=9
f=[F*[0]for i in'7'*F]
c=Canvas(T,bg='white',width=S*F,height=S*F)
c.pack()
def p(x,y,a):f[y][x]=f[y][x]or c.create_rectangle(x*S,y*S,x*S+S,y*S+S,fill='gray')if a else c.delete(f[y][x])
r=1
def R(e):global r;r=1-r
exec("c.bind('<Button-%i>',lambda e:p(e.x/S,e.y/S,%i));c.bind('<B%i-Motion>',lambda e:p(e.x/S,e.y/S,%i));"*2%(1,1,1,1,3,0,3,0))
c.bind('<Button-2>',R)
def L():
 T.after(99,L)
 if r:return
 g=copy.deepcopy(f)
 for y in z(F):
  for x in z(F):
   n=8
   for j in z(-1,2):
    for i in z(-1,2):
     if i or j:n-=not g[(y+j)%F][(x+i)%F]
   if 1<n<4:
    if n==3and not g[y][x]:p(x,y,1)
   else:p(x,y,0)
L()
T.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't follow the game of life rules correctly.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Oh really?

Comment: really.  You have an indentation error in your second version.  The section starting with `if 1<n<4:` should be indented at the same level as `for j in z(-1,2):`

Answer (score 2):

## Postscript <del>529</del> 515

Started with the example from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life). Invoke with a filename argument (`gs -- gol.ps pulsar`), the file containing 20*20 binary numbers (separated by space). Infinite loop: draw board, wait for enter, calculate next generation.

```
[/f ARGUMENTS 0 get(r)file/n 20>>begin[/m
n 1 sub/b[n{[n{f token pop}repeat]}repeat]/c 400
n div/F{dup 0 lt{n add}if dup n ge{n sub}if}>>begin{0
1 m{dup 0 1 m{2 copy b exch get exch get 1 xor setgray
c mul exch c mul c c rectfill dup}for pop pop}for
showpage/b[0 1 m{/x exch def[0 1 m{/y exch def 0
y 1 sub 1 y 1 add{F dup x 1 sub 1 x
1 add{F b exch get exch get 3 2 roll add exch
dup}for pop pop}for b x get y get sub b x get y get
0 eq{3 eq{1}{0}ifelse}{dup 2 eq exch 3 eq
or{1}{0}ifelse}ifelse}for]}for]def}loop
```

Spaced, with a few stack comments (just the ones I needed).

```
[
/f ARGUMENTS 0 get(r)file
/n 20
/sz 400
%/r{rand 2147483647 div}
>>begin
[
/m n 1 sub
/b[
%n{[n{r .15 le{1}{0}ifelse}repeat]}repeat
 n{[n{f token pop}repeat]}repeat
]
/c sz n div
/F{dup 0 lt{n add}if dup n ge{n sub}if}
>>begin
{
    0 1 m{dup % y y
    0 1 m{ % y y x
        2 copy b exch get exch get 1 xor setgray
        c mul exch c mul c c rectfill
        dup 
    }for pop pop}for
    pstack
    showpage
    /b[0 1 m{/x exch def
      [0 1 m{/y exch def
          0   
          y 1 sub 1 y 1 add{F dup %s y y
          x 1 sub 1 x 1 add{F %s y y x
              b exch get exch get %s y bxy
              3 2 roll add exch %s+bxy y
              dup %s y y
          }for pop pop}for
          b x get y get sub
          b x get y get
          0 eq{3 eq{1}{0}ifelse}{dup 2 eq exch 3 eq or{1}{0}ifelse}ifelse
      }for]
      }for]def
}loop
```

pulsar data file:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 456 bytes

While I know this is an old post, I couldn't help myself from giving it a shot.  The initial board can be any size as long as you draw a border around it and have an extra space on the last line.

**Golf.py**

```
import time,itertools as w,sys;t,q=map(lambda x:list(x[:-1]),sys.stdin.readlines()),list(w.product(range(-1,2),range(-1,2)));del q[4];n=map(lambda x:x[:],t[:])
while time.sleep(0.1)==None:
 for j in range(1,len(t)-1):
  for i in range(1,len(t[j])-1):x=sum(map(lambda s:1 if t[j+s[0]][i+s[1]]in'@'else 0,q));f=t[j][i];n[j][i]='@'if(f=='@'and(x==3 or x==2))or(f==' 'and x==3)else' '
 t=map(lambda x:x[:],n[:]);print'\n'.join(list(map(lambda x:''.join(x),t)))
```

**Input.txt** (note the extra space on the last line)

```
+----------------------------------------+
|                    @                   |
|                     @                  |
|                   @@@                  |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
|                                        |
+----------------------------------------+
```

**How to Run**

```
python Golf.py < input.txt
```

Comment: `time.sleep(0.1)==None` => `not time.sleep(.1)`, `(f=='@'and(x==3 or x==2`))or(f==' 'and x==3) => `x==3or f=='@'and x==2`

Comment: ^, You forgot one, `1 if`=>`1if`.

Answer (score 2):

## Processing <del>270,261</del> 249 bytes

Grid is the 100*100 pixels of screen, input comes in the form of a png picture

```
void setup(){image(loadImage("g.png"),0,0);}void draw(){loadPixels();int n,i=0,j,l=10000;int[]a=new int[l],p=pixels;for(;i<l;a[i]=n==5?-1<<24:n==6?p[i]:-1,i++)for(j=n=0;j<9;j++)n+=j!=4?p[(i+l-1+j%3+100*(j/3-1))%l]&1:0;arrayCopy(a,p);updatePixels();}
```

Ungolfed

```
void setup() {
  image(loadImage("g.png"), 0, 0);
}
void draw() {
  loadPixels();
  int c=100, i=0, n, l=c*c, b=color(0);
  int[]a=new int[l], p=pixels;
  for (; i<l; i++) {
    n=p[(i+l-101)%l]&1;
    n+=p[(i+l-100)%l]&1;
    n+=p[(i+l-99)%l]&1;
    n+=p[(i+l-1)%l]&1;
    n+=p[(i+1)%l]&1;
    n+=p[(i+99)%l]&1;
    n+=p[(i+100)%l]&1;
    n+=p[(i+101)%l]&1;
    a[i]=n==5?b:p[i]==b&&n==6?b:-1;
  }
  arrayCopy(a, pixels, l);
  updatePixels();
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

## Python with numpy and matplotlib

### 765 characters

This script is quite optimized, since it uses no loops: only numpy functions or animations loops (that are like recursion). So even if its quite long, I think that it was interesting to put it here (and it could be really shorter, but I just took my classic program, and simplified it).

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as P;import numpy as N;from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation;neighbours=lambda G:N.sum([N.roll(N.roll(G,y,1),x,0)for x in(-1,0,1)for y in(-1,0,1)if x+y],axis=0);A=N.array
class G:
    o=1
    def __init__(Z,e,r):Z.g=N.random.rand(e,r)<.3;Z.r=lambda a,v:N.logical_or(N.any(A([v==3]),axis=0),N.logical_and(a,N.any(A([N.logical_or(v==2,v==3)]),axis=0)))
    def S(Z):Z.g=(Z.r(Z.g,neighbours(Z.g)),Z.g)[Z.o];return Z.g
    def P(Z,x):Z.o^=1
    def G(Z,n):
        for _ in[0]*n:Z.S()
        return Z.g
    def R(Z,skip=0,t=0):l=P.figure();im=P.imshow(Z.g,cmap="Greys");l.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',Z.P);FuncAnimation(l,lambda I:(im.set_array(Z.G(skip+1)),[im])[-1],interval=1,blit=1);P.show()
life=G(100,100);life.R(t=1)
```

If you want to change the grid, you can simply replace the statement:

```python
life.fill()
```

That fills randomly the center part of the grid, by:

```python
life.g=matrix
```

Where matrix is your grid, a numpy booleans array.

This code comes from a more complex code, this one :

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

out = __import__('sys').stdout.write

neighbours = lambda grid: np.sum([
    np.roll(np.roll(grid, y, 1), x, 0)
    for x in (-1, 0, 1) for y in (-1, 0, 1)
    if x or y
], axis=0)
neighbours.__doc__ = """# function that returns sum of neighbours of all the
cells for a given grid"""


class GOL:
    """Object to run a game of life - type Cellular Automaton"""
    on = True  # variable: bool; is the simulation runing ?
    i = 0  # generation number

    def __init__(self, dim_x=800, dim_y=400, R=None, show_gen=False):
        """dim_x and dim_y are the batch size

        R is the rule, specified as here: B___/S___
        example: B3/S23 for the classic game of life.
        default value: B3/S23"""
        if R is None:
            self.B, self.S = ([3], [2, 3])
        else:
            self.B, self.S = [list(map(int, p)) for p in R.split("/")]
        self.shape = (dim_y, dim_x)  # variable:tuple(int, int); grid shape
        self.g = np.zeros(self.shape) == 1  # variable:np.array()
        self.showGen = show_gen  # variable:bool; print the gen number ?

        if R is None:  # default rule: a bit speedier (no loops)
            # function to compute next generation for the conway's game of life
            self.rule = lambda actuel, voisins: \
                np.logical_or(
                    np.any(
                        np.array([voisins == 3]),
                        axis=0
                    ),
                    np.logical_and(
                        actuel,
                        np.any(
                            np.array([
                                np.logical_or(
                                    voisins == 2,
                                    voisins == 3
                                )
                            ]),
                            axis=0)
                    ))
        else:  # other rules
            # function to compute the next generation for any given rule
            self.rule = lambda actuel, voisins: \
                np.logical_or(
                    np.any(
                        np.array([voisins == b for b in self.B]),
                        axis=0
                    ),
                    np.logical_and(
                        actuel,
                        np.any(
                            np.array([voisins == s for s in self.S]),
                            axis=0)
                    ))

    def __str__(self):
        """how to print the automata (info : rule and rule number)"""
        return "I'm a life-like automata" \
               '\nmy rule : B' + ''.join(map(str, self.B)) +\
               '/S' + ''.join(map(str, self.S)) \
               + "\nmy hexa-code :  " + str(self.rule_number())

    def fill(self, mode, d=.3, n=10):
        """Random filling of the grid
        mode : {'rNoise', 'cloud', 'parse'}
        rNoise:
            fill all the grid with the density d
        cloud:
            fill a third of the grid with the density d
        parse:
            fill n cells exactly in the grid (no overlappings)
        """
        self.g &= False
        s0, s1 = self.shape
        if mode == "rNoise":
            self.g = np.random.rand(*self.g.shape) < d

        elif mode == "cloud":

            self.g[s0 // 3: s0 // 3 * 2, s1 // 3: s1 // 3 * 2] = (
                np.random.rand(s0 // 3, s1 // 3) < d)

        elif mode == "parse":
            for _ in range(n):
                x, y = np.random.randint(s1), np.random.randint(s0)
                while self.g[y, x]:
                    x, y = np.random.randint(s1), np.random.randint(s0)
                self.g[y, x] = True  # it's a boolean list !!!

    def step(self):
        """Compute the next generation and refresh the grid"""
        if self.on:
            self.i += 1
            # if self.showGen and not self.i % 10:
            #     out("generation " + str(self.i))
            self.g = self.rule(self.g, neighbours(self.g))
        return self.g

    def pause(self, x):
        """Action for the animation : swich the value of self.on"""
        self.on ^= True

    def gen(self, n):
        """Generate n generations """
        for _ in [0] * n:
            self.step()
        return self.g

    def run(self, skip=0, t=0, showGen=False):
        """Run the CA with a matplotlib animation graphics"""
        self.showGen = showGen
        fig = plt.figure()
        im = plt.imshow(self.g, cmap="Greys")
        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.pause)

        FuncAnimation(fig,
                      lambda i: (im.set_array(self.gen(skip + 1)), [im])[-1],
                      interval=t,
                      blit=True)
        plt.show()

    def rule_number(self):
        return sum(2 ** (np.hstack((np.array(self.B), np.array(self.S) + 9))))


new_rule = lambda: (
    np.arange(8)[np.random.rand(8) > .5],
    np.arange(8)[np.random.rand(8) > .5]
)

new_rule.__doc__ == """returns a random rule"""


life = GOL(600, 600, R="3/23")
life.fill("cloud")
print(life)
life.run(t=1, showGen=True)
```

This long version allows you to chose any life-like rule, and to fill the grid with different random modes.

Comment: Welcome to the site! There are a couple of obvious golfs here (`GOL` -> `G`, `True` -> `1`, `False` -> `0`), but otherwise, this is an impressive first answer. Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page for less obvious ways to save bytes!

Comment: I got it down to about 725 bytes with a minifier, see https://pypi.org/project/python-minifier/

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 676

Sorry Griffin, I just couldn't look at your code and not re-write it slightly... had to shave off two characters but it was damn worth it!

`b=[];r=c=s=20;U=document;onload=function(){for(z=E=0;z<c;++z)for(b.push(t=[]),j=0;j<r;j++)with(U.body.appendChild(U.createElement("button")))t.push(0),id=z+"_"+j,style.position="absolute",style.left=s*j+"px",style.top=s*z+"px",onclick=a}; ondblclick=function(){A=E=E?clearInterval(A):setInterval(function(){Q=[];for(z=0;z<c;++z){R=[];for(j=0;j<r;)W=(c+z-1)%c,X=(c+z+1)%c,Y=(r+j-1)%r,Z=(r+j+1)%r,n=b[W][Y]+b[z][Y]+b[X][Y]+b[W][j]+b[X][j]+b[W][Z]+b[z][Z]+b[X][Z],R.push(b[z][j++]?4>n&&1<n:3==n);Q.push(R)}b=Q.slice();d()})};function a(e){E?0:P=e.target.id.split("_");b[P[0]][P[1]]^=1;d()}function d(){for(z=0;z<c;++z)for(j=0;j<r;)U.getElementById(z+"_"+j).innerHTML=b[z][j++]-0}`

But as they say, it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission... ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Octave (153)

the same as Matlab by DenDenDo at [Shortest Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3434/shortest-game-of-life/38577#38577) , but had to change imshow to imagesc:

```
b=uint8(rand(20)<0.2)
s=@(m)imfilter(m,[1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1],'circular')
p=@(m,n)uint8((n==3)|(m&(n==2)))
while 1
imagesc(b)
drawnow
b=p(b,s(b))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2: 334 Bytes

Only 6 years late.

```
import time
s='';s=map(list,iter(raw_input,s));k=len(s);l=(-1,0,1);n=int;z=range
while 1:
 r=[[0]*k for i in z(k)]
 for i in z(k*k):
  a,b=i//k,i%k
  m,g=sum([n(s[(a+c)%k][(b+d)%k])for c in l for d in l if c|d]),n(s[a][b])
  r[a][b]=n((m==2)&g or m==3)
  print'*'if r[a][b]else' ',
  if b-k+1==0:print
 s=r;time.sleep(.2);print"\033c"
```

You can run it like:

```
python gol.py
0000000
0001000
0000100
0011100
0000000
0000000
0000000
```

Where the 0s and 1s represent dead and live cells, an extra newline at the end begins execution.

Grids must be square.

It's easier to run than the shortest python one, supports any sized grids, and looks pretty when run.

It's also 100 bytes more, so there's that.

Answer (score 1):

#### HTML and Javascript, 248 characters

```
<script>b=[];setInterval(()=>x.innerHTML=(b=b.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>+(([0,1,2,4,6,8,9,10].reduce((s,n)=>s+((b[y-1+(n>>2)]||[])[x+n%4-1]||0),0)|c)==3)))).map(r=>`<tr>${r.map(v=>`<td>${'⬜⬛'[v]}`).join('')}`).join(''),999)</script><table id='x'>
```

Run it by opening the web developer console and setting the global variable `b` (for "board") to a 2D-array of 0 (dead) and 1 (alive) values, for example:

`b=new Array(32).fill(0).map(() => new Array(32).fill(0).map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)))`

The core of this is the following:

### Javascript, 114 characters

```
l=b=>b.map((r,y)=>r.map((c,x)=>+(([0,1,2,4,6,8,9,10].reduce((s,n)=>s+((b[y-1+(n>>2)]||[])[x+n%4-1]||0),0)|c)==3)))
```

Annotated as follows:

```
l=       // l="Life"
  b=>    // Function that takes a board (2D array of ints that are 1 or 0)
  b.map( // map each row 
    (
      r, // the row (array of 1s and 0s)
      y  // index is the y position of the row
    )=>
    r.map( //map each cell
      (
        c, // the cell value (0, or 1)
        x  // index is the x position
      )=>(+( //this whole thing will return true or false, convert to 1 or 0
        // these magic numbers represent the eight neighbors of a cell
        // they map to x, y offsets (used below):
        // value  x     y
        //      n%4-1 (n>>2)-1
        [
          0, //  -1    -1
          1, //   0    -1
          2, //   1    -1
          4, //  -1     0
          6, //   1     0
          8, //   1    -1
          9, //   1     0
          10 //   1     1
        ]
        .reduce( //get the number of neighbors that are alive (===1)
          (
            s, // the accumulator (sum of alive neighbors so far)
            n  // the number from the list of magic numbers above
          )=>
          s+(  // add to the accumulator
            (
              b[            // find the row containing the neighbor
                y-1+(n>>2)  // A shorter way of expressing y+Math.floor(n/4)-1
              ]||[]         // if index is -1 or b.length, empty array
            )[              // within the row, find the value
              x+n%4-1       // offset x value (see table above)
            ]||0            // coalesce undefined(x is -1 or r.length) to 0
          ),0               // initial value for neighborCount accumulator
        )|c                 // | bitwise or with the value of the cell, 1 or zero
                            // if the cell is dead (0), this has no effect
                            // if the cell is alive (1), this changes 2 to 3
      )==3)                 // 3 means either:
                            // 3 neighbors or
                            // 2 neighbors and an alive cell (the rules for life)
    )
)
```

More info here: https://github.com/noops-challenge/golfbot/blob/master/challenges/conways-life/entries/davidmfoley

Answer (score 1):

## QBasic, <s>276</s> 271 bytes

<sup>-5 bytes thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126)</sup>

```
DIM a(20,20)
DO
FOR y=0TO 19
FOR x=0TO 19
IF j THEN c=a(x,y)\2ELSE c=INPUT$(1)>"0
a(x,y)=c
NEXT x,y
CLS
FOR y=0TO 19
?
FOR x=0TO 19
?a(x,y);
n=0
FOR j=19TO 21
FOR i=19TO 21
n=n-a((x+i)MOD 20,(y+j)MOD 20)MOD 2
NEXT i,j
a(x,y)=2*(n=3)+(1-2*(n=4))*a(x,y)
NEXT x,y
SLEEP
LOOP
```

[Ways to run QBasic](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7138/16766)

**Disclaimer:** This golfed version is *extremely* user-unfriendly. See below for details and a somewhat friendlier version.

#### Algorithm

We store the grid in the 2D array `a`. A value of `0` is a dead cell; a value of `-1` (QBasic's default truthy value) is a living cell.

The whole program is wrapped in an infinite `DO ... LOOP`. On the first iteration, `j` is `0`, and so the first nested `FOR` loop initializes the array from user input (`c=INPUT$(1)>"0`). We then clear the screen with `CLS` and proceed to the next set of nested loops. Before each row `y`, we print a newline (`?`). Then for each cell at column `x`:

- We print the cell's value, suppressing the trailing newline (`?a(x,y);`).
- We loop over the 3x3 neighborhood around the cell. The loop indices `j` and `i` are essentially going from -1 to 1, but in QBasic, `(-1) MOD num` is `-1` rather than `num - 1`, so to avoid any negative numbers we loop from 19 to 21 instead.
- For each living cell in the neighborhood, we add `1` to `n`.
- After the loop, we subtract 2 from the cell's value if it will be alive at the next step. A more straightforward but less golfy way to write the expression is `a(x,y) = a(x,y) - 2 * ((n=3) - (n=4)*a(x,y))`: subtract 2 if `n=3` or if `n=4` and `a(x,y)` is true (`-1`).

After the `FOR` loops, `SLEEP` pauses until the user presses a key. We then return to the top. At this point, the elements in array `a` can have any of four values:

- `0` is a cell that was dead last step and will remain dead.
- `-1` is a cell that was alive last step but will die.
- `-2` is a cell that was dead last step but will come alive.
- `-3` is a cell that was alive last step and will remain alive.

When we reach the first nested `FOR` loop again, `j` is now truthy (having been used as a loop index), so we integer-divide each element by 2 (`c=a(x,y)\2`). Values of `0` and `-1` become `0` (dead), and values of `-2` and `-3` become `-1` (alive).

#### I/O format and caveats; or: Don't Run This Code

The input format for this code is just awful. The user is expected to press a key 400 times to initialize the 400 cells. (Any key with an ASCII value of 48 (`"0"`) or less is a dead cell; any key with a greater ASCII value is a living cell.) The worst part: *none of this input is echoed to the screen*. You just have to keep count in your head and hope you didn't double-press a key. In practice? Something always goes wrong.

Once all the input has been received, the raw array values are output. Because of the way QBasic formats numeric output, they do line up in a grid, like this--

```
 0 -1  0 
 0  0 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

--but it's still not the nicest output format.

Rather than an animation per se, the code waits for a user keypress between iterations. I think this fits the spec (it shows each step long enough to be seen), and it's the golfiest way to pause in QBasic. `SLEEP 1` would wait one second between each iteration for +2 bytes.

A couple more caveats:

- The code runs as an infinite loop, so you'll have to kill the program to make it exit.
- The sequence `2ELSE` on line 5 is correctly parsed as `2 ELSE` by actual QBasic, but the QB64 emulator has trouble with it, expecting the `2E` sequence to be the start of a number in scientific notation. You'll have to add in the space if you're using QB64.

All that to say: I don't recommend you run this code as-is. Either change the array size to 5x5 (which makes the input manageable and still allows for a glider) or use the nicer version.

#### Nicer version, 319 bytes

It's still not what I'd call user-friendly, but here's a version I'm actually willing to run:

```
DIM a(20,20)
1CLS
FOR y=0TO 19
IF j=0THEN INPUT r$
FOR x=0TO 19
IF j THEN c=a(x,y)\2 ELSE c=MID$(r$,x+1,1)>"0
a(x,y)=c
NEXT x,y
CLS
FOR y=0TO 19
?
FOR x=0TO 19
?CHR$(34-a(x,y));
n=0
FOR j=19TO 21
FOR i=19TO 21
n=n-a((x+i)MOD 20,(y+j)MOD 20)MOD 2
NEXT i,j
a(x,y)=2*(n=3)+(1-2*(n=4))*a(x,y)
NEXT x,y
IF"!">INPUT$(1)GOTO 1
```

Differences:

- This version takes input line by line. There is a prompt, and characters are echoed as they're typed; you can even backspace if you make a mistake. The same range of ASCII values represents dead vs. living, with the caveat that this form of input doesn't play well with space, double quote, or comma. I recommend `.` for dead cells and a letter for living ones. You can also give it lines shorter than 20 characters, and it will pad them out with dead cells--super convenient.
- Output is a grid of characters: `"` for dead cells, `#` for living ones.
- Press space or enter to go to the next step; any other printable ASCII character ends the program.

Comment: Is there a good online emulator for Qbasic that you could link so we can see it running?

Comment: You can recycle ```j``` instead of ```z``` to save 4 bytes by removing ```z=1```.

Comment: And save another 1 byte by changing ```FOR``` ```FOR``` ```NEXT``` ```?``` ```NEXT``` into ```FOR``` ```?``` ```FOR``` ```NEXT x,y```

Comment: Ah, nice, thanks! QBasic is runnable online at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack); I've added a link to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  QB64 was actually quite painless to install on my computer, so super-useful to know the caveats...

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>358</s> 216 bytes

```powershell
param($a)for(){cls;$a
$a=0..19|%{$l=-join($a[,-1+0..19+0]|%{$_[-1]+$_+$_[0]})[$_,++$_,++$_]
-join(23..42|%{$x=$_;switch(($l[(-23,-22,-21,-1,1,21,22,23|%{$x+$_})]-eq'X').count){2{$l[$x]}3{'X'}default{'.'}}})}
sleep 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zZHNasMwDMfveYoeNGzjD2Jnl1HyHgZjgslc2uE2WZLSgutn99xut2XHsQlLQj/9JQQeh4uf5r0PIefRTe6IwZHdMGES@zBvwVXg2loI@XJ7ihBa/jYcTkVjGJf0wWlt763OcGkpdOWZ2iZioGOUfgVbfc6pRohndZdfW@i28@Ww9HuMIRjMVcO4UsVlWc0kK7mUqnmoy45ELPfvSCMi@uF8WkhU5SADV5uaWHB69Tt3DktEAqWUSKrm4P24kSnnjLT4ZhqxCokV@1Ouf9LrVa61/l/3/zJf/ccP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 237 bytes

```hs
import Data.Set
moore a=fromList$zipWith(+)a<$>[[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1],[0,-1],[0,1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1]]
a#b=elem(size$intersection b$moore a)$3:[2|member a b]
step b=Data.Set.filter(#b)$union b$unions$moore<$>elems b
life b=iterate step b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU8xbsMwDNz9CgHRYKOJobSdirpTxwwBMmQwNFAtjRCRLENiliB/d6TIng4k73h3F4hXtHaeyU0@sPgFhvaEXDnvAwrohuDdgSLLO01n4kv91sC3/On73X672@ttRlUgT6os1WtYGIWQ77qCjenQoqsj3VHSyBgi/jH5URi5eDby46t/fzh0BoMAYXQVGSdhujVdO5BNynpjGnkbi/iFsfxIAbNJFKayNGBSUqIDoyiPZgc0dlNI/vIY0N7@sWW4oviUmS/X0v3aTi0VlNbzEw)

Answer (score 1):

These solutions all use roughly the same algorithm.

The input board is given as the first argument `argv[1]`, the output is printed to `stdout`.

I wrote this runner https://github.com/roguh/gameoflife to use these programs as part of an animation. It can basically use any binary or script that accepts a GoL board as its first argv and outputs the next step.

### Usage

```
python gol.py "$(cat board.txt)"
luajit gol.lua "$(cat board.txt)"
ocaml gol.ml "$(cat board.txt)"  # you can also compile the .ml file
```

## OCaml, 209 bytes

Late but latest.

`Sys.argv.(1)|>String.mapi(fun i c->match(c,List.fold_left(fun a d->a+if i+d>=0&&i+d<1055&&Sys.argv.(1).[i+d]=='#'then 1 else 0)0[-32;-33;-34;-1;1;32;33;34])with '\n',_->c|_,2->c|_,3->'#'|_->'.')|>print_endline`

## Python, 170 bytes

`for i in range(1055):print(B[i]=='\n'and'\n'or f"..{B[i]}#......"[[0<=A+i<1055 and B[A+i]for A in[-33,33,-1,1,32,-34,34,-32]].count('#')],end='')`

## Lua, 211 bytes

`io.write` was key here.

`b=arg[1]for i=1,#b do function x(d)j=i+d return j and j<#b and b:sub(j,j)=="#"and 1 or 0 end c=b:sub(i,i)t=x(34)+x(33)+x(32)+x(1)+x(-1)+x(-32)+x(-33)+x(-34)io.write((c=="\n"or t==2)and c or t==3 and"#"or".")end`

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 201 bytes (not tested)

```php
for($s=file(f);print"\n";$s=$t)foreach($s as$y=>$r)for($x=-print"
";"
"<$c=$s[$y][++$x];print$t[$y][$x]=" X"[$n<4&$n>2-$a])for($n=-$a=$c>A,$i=$x-!!$x-1;$i++<=$x;)for($k=$y-2;$k++<=$y;)$n+=$s[$k][$i]>A;
```

Run with `-nr`.

**breakdown**

```php
for($s=file(f);                         # import input from file "f"
    print"\n";                              # infinite loop: 1. print newline
    $s=$t)                                  # 3. copy target to source, next iteration
    foreach($s as$y=>$r)                    # 2. loop through lines
        for($x=-print"\n";"\n"<$c=$s[$y][++$x]; # print newline, loop $x/$c through line characters (before line break)
            print                                   # 5. print new cell
                $t[$y][$x]=" X"[$n>2-$a&$n<4])      # 4. new cell is alive if neighbour count<4 and >2 (>1 if alive)
            for($n=-                                # 2. init neighbour count: exclude self
                $a=$c>A,                            # 1. $a=cell is alife
                $i=$x-!!$x-1;$i++<=$x;)             # 3. loop $i from one left to one right of current position
                for($k=$y-2;$k++<=$y;)                  # loop $k from one above to one below current position
                    $n+=$s[$k][$i]>A;                       # increase neighbor count if neighbour is alife
```

Answer (score 0):

## VBA (Excel), 546<sup>*</sup> Bytes

```vb
Sub t()
f=[a1:t20]
For Each c In f.Cells
c.Value=""
r=c.Row
l=c.Column
If g(r,0,0,l,-1,0)Then h=h+1
If g(r,0,0,l,1,21)Then h=h+1
If g(r,-1,0,l,0,0)Then h=h+1
If g(r,1,21,l,0,0)Then h=h+1
If g(r,1,21,l,-1,0)Then h=h+1
If g(r,-1,0,l,1,21)Then h=h+1
If g(r,-1,0,l,-1,0)Then h=h+1
If g(r,1,21,l,1,21)Then h=h+1
If h=3Or(h=2And c.Interior.Color=0)Then c.Value="A"
Next
f.Interior.ColorIndex=0
For Each c In f
If c.Value="A"Then c.Interior.Color=0
Next
End Sub
Function g(r,e,f,c,q,z)
g=(Cells(IIf(r+e=f,Abs(f-20),r+e),IIf(c+q=z,Abs(z-20),c+q)).Interior.Color=0)
End Function
```

Create the living cells by highlighting cells in A1:T20 and coloring them black.

<sup>*</sup>When t is run, it executes a single tick. I added a button on mine to click repeatedly. If this doesn't satisfy the requirements, I'll add a do-->while[counta(f)]>0 and a DoEvents for +34 bytes.

*[I'll edit this with a link when I upload a copy of my macro-enabled Excel doc]*

Comment: This answer appears to be non-functional for a couple of reasons, namely the declaration of f should include a `set` clause as otherwise `f.cells` will invoke an object required error as f will be instanciated as a 20 x 20 Array. Secondly, when this is corrected the given solution does not implement the rules of conways game of life properly. I suggest using a simple blinker oscillator as a future test case